# Center figure that is wider than \textwidth

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, margins

I have a `figure` that is wider than the `\textwidth` of my document. (I don't want to change the `\textwidth`.) As a result, the leftmost part of the `figure` is flush with the left margin, while the rightmost part spills into the right margin too much. I'd like to center the `figure`, so that it will exceed the `\textwidth` equally on both sides.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

Put the content of your `figure` environment into a `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}` macro. This will center its content to the normal text width even if it is wider than that. See also my similar answer to [Place figures side by side, spill into outer margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin/10507#10507).

The image can also be aligned to the left and right using `[l]` and `[r]`, which makes the image lap into the right or left margin, respectively.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{image}}%
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:key}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Starting from 2011/08/13 you can also use `adjustbox` package for such alignments. For centering use the `center=<length>` which centers the content in the given length. The length is optional and defaults to `\linewidth` which is normally identical to `\textwidth`. There is also `left` and `right` as well as `inner` and `outer`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}[2011/08/13]
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,center]{image}%
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:key}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: At http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57709/2552 there's the suggestion of using `\centerline{\includegraphics}`. Could you comment on whether there are any drawbacks with that approach compared to your suggestions (in the interest of a "canonical answer")?

Comment: @Jake: `\centerline` is actually a plainTeX macro and does not leave-vmode, i.e. you need to add `\leavevmode` before it to make sure it is not accidentally stacked in vertical mode with some following `\hbox`. Beside this the `center` key of `adjustbox` **works the exact same way as `\centerline`, just with on optional width argument.**

Comment: Applying the makebox approach, the figure caption is still centered within the actual textblock, not within the area spanned by the overlarge makebox/figure. Is there a fix to that?

Comment: @bioslime: The captions are build be special code which might fix the width to `\textwidth`. Have a look at `caption` package, maybe it allows to change this.

Comment: Good hint. And indeed, simply replace `\caption` and `\label` to include ```\captionsetup[figure]{margin={10pt,\omargin}}
\captionof{figure}{\label{img}Description}```.Now margin definies the inner/outer margin in respect to linewidth(or textwidth?). Therefore, define the margin that breaks out e.g. like ``\newlength\omargin
\setlength\omargin\linewidth
\addtolength\omargin{-1.2\linewidth} % in case that is the total image width
\addtolength\omargin{+10pt} % add the margin you want``. Also when the captionsetup is placed within the environment it will only affect this caption.

Comment: I found `\makebox[0pt]{...}` worked well. (It is from another answer somewhere but I mention it here as this is the one duplicates are getting linked to.)

Comment: As it turns out, this also removes the warning about to full hbox.

Comment: In LyX all you need is adding `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to the preamble and then add `center` to Graphics' LaTeX options. It works like a charm!

Comment: In case your figure is not inside a `figure` environment, make sure to remove the indentation or you will find your figure strangely deported on the right: `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{your figure}`.

Comment: So unfortunate that it works for `includegraphics` but not for `includesvg`. `\centerline{}` works for the later, though.

Comment: @MartinScharrer @cfr I also mention that `\makebox[1.1\textwidth][c]{...}` does not give the wanted behaviour.

Comment: @Karlo It isn't surprising that wouldn't work if the behaviour is centring a too-wide graphic, though, since the box will be too wide, too. You have to lie ;).

Answer (score 70):

If you're using the `memoir` class, the `\centerfloat` command does that:

```
\begin{figure}
\centerfloat
% your figure, caption and label
\end{figure}
```

If you're using another class, you can define the same command by grabbing its code from `memoir`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\centerfloat}{%
  \parindent \z@
  \leftskip \z@ \@plus 1fil \@minus \textwidth
  \rightskip\leftskip
  \parfillskip \z@skip}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This is extremely useful! I use this all the time! Thank you for posting this.

Comment: I have looked for this for hours now... this is the **only** thing that worked for me since I've a listing in my table that is too wide. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow, I never even knew that memoir had this genius piece of code. I am editing exam questions written in latex and the author insisted on having an image width of exactly 18cm, but the margins were completely off and the image was sticking out past the page border. This definetely saved me some trouble!

Comment: Extremely useful! Thanks especially for the code snippet so I don't necessarily have to use package `memoir`

Answer (score 20):

You could also use the [`changepage`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/changepage) package, which defines the `adjustwidth` environment that allows an environment that spills out across the margins.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe=true,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{changepage}                 % adjust margins for selected portions
\usepackage{lipsum}

% wide page for side by side figures, tables, etc
\newlength{\offsetpage}
\setlength{\offsetpage}{1.0cm}
\newenvironment{widepage}{\begin{adjustwidth}{-\offsetpage}{-\offsetpage}%
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{2\offsetpage}}%
{\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{widepage}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{7}rr}
        \toprule
            & 2008/09 & 2009/10 & 2010/11 & 2011/12 & 2012/13 & --2011/12 & --2012/13  & --2012/13 \\
        \midrule
        SY  & 6764    & 8155    & 8847    & 9682    & 8840    & 43.14\%   & $-8.70\%$  & 30.70\%   \\
        CA  & 4159    & 5745    & 5963    & 6585    & 5887    & 58.33\%   & $-10.60\%$ & 41.55\%   \\
        RC  & 6625    & 8033    & 8192    & 8669    & 8454    & $30.85\%$ & $-2.48\%$  & 27.60\%   \\
        ELC & 2785    & 3883    & 4404    & 4709    & 4860    & $69.08\%$ & 3.21\%     & 74.50\%   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{widepage}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: My solution 

\begin{figure}[htb!]
 \begin{widepage}
 \centering
 \subfigure[...]{\label{...}\includegraphics[width=0.325\linewidth]{...}}
 \subfigure[...]{\label{...}\includegraphics[width=0.325\linewidth]{...}}
 \subfigure[...]{\label{...}\includegraphics[width=0.325\linewidth]{...}}
 \end{widepage}
 \caption{...}
 \label{...}
\end{figure}

Comment: Finally, this works! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

There is a far more simpler answer from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57709/167352).

The solution is :

```
\centerline{\includegraphics{...}}
```

Comment: Yes this works and is very simple!