# Orgchart in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

The questions below arose after trying to use code from an answer to the question at [TikZ-tree: edge-alignment in horizontal org-chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46476/tikz-tree-edge-alignment-in-horizontal-org-chart)

Question 1: As you can see I changed paper format to use B (11x17) and the picture scaled accordingly including text inside the boxes. As smaller text size is required, I tried changing 12pt to 10pt. Instead of changing text size, it changed width of the boxes. What is required in the code to use smaller text without changing tree layout?

Question 2: Why does new line `\\` work in the teammate and subordinate styles, but not in Supervisor node? Does it need its own style?

Question 3: Is it possible to keep the units uniform, i.e. not use `pt, cm, ex, em` but limit the use of units to the minimum required?

Question 4: I could not find Tikz package and trees library at CTAN. Where can I find documentation?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape,paper=ansibpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west, minimum height=2.5em]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

\begin{tikzpicture}[
teammate/.style={text centered, text width=3cm, fill=gray!10},
subordinate/.style={%
    grow=down, xshift=0em,
    text centered, text width=3cm,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.225) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
    level1/.style ={level distance=8ex},
    level2/.style ={level distance=16ex},
    level3/.style ={level distance=24ex},
    level4/.style ={level distance=32ex},
    level5/.style ={level distance=40ex},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=10em}]
    % Supervisor
    \node[anchor=south]{Supervisor \\ Supervisory position}
    [edge from parent fork down]

    % Teammate and Subordinates
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate1}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate\\Position1\\Location1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Subordinate3}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Subordinate4\\Position4\\Location4}}
        child[subordinate,level5] {node {Subordinate5\\Position5\\Location5}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate2}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate3}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate\\two lines}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}     
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Subordinate3}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate4}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate5}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {First\\Subordinate}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{This is an org chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Documentation: starts p 475 sec 53 of the `tikz` manual. The libraries don't (generally) have separate documentation. Change measures such as `ex` to something independent of font size if you want only the text size to change. `cm` is obviously OK but `ex`, `em` etc. all dependent on the font. (Roughly speaking... generally... usually...)

Comment: Add `text width=4cm, text centered` to the supervisor node to get the line break.

Comment: Re. question 4, see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: @cfr This works great, but then supervisor's box overlaps its connecting lines and adding `level distance=2.5cm` to any stile does not seem to add any distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supervisor node is missing the width and alignment style. The other nodes already have `text centered, text width=3cm` as style, which allows line breaking.

Suggestion: start with a basic style, and inherit this style, add or change settings when needed.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  position/.style    = {text centered, text width=3cm},
  supervisor/.style  = {position, text width=4cm, anchor=south},
  teammate/.style    = {position, fill=gray!10},
  subordinate/.style = {position,
      grow=down, xshift=0em,
      ...
```

That was Q1, regarding Q1 and Q3: use styles as much as you can, Q4: [PGF on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/). (Tipp: the actual name of the package is PGF, TikZ is just the frontend part).