# Simplified family tree in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a simplified family tree like the one below using TikZ.

[image: Family tree]

I know about the [genealogytree](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree) package and [How can I improve this family tree in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39696/how-can-i-improve-this-family-tree-in-tikz), but those trees are too complicated, since they have names and use colours. I'm looking for something much simpler like the one above.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you after exactly? Do you need only this one drawing or would you like to draw several different trees?

Comment: Ideally, I’d like something that would be generalizable to arbitrary trees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how you want to use this, but you can always define a few styles with Ti*k*Z which you can then use for creating different family trees.

This may get you started (maybe not the most elegant way to do this):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes}

\tikzset{
    family tree/.style={
        every node/.style={
            inner sep=0pt
        },
        person/.style={
            minimum size=15pt,
            circle
        },
        woman/.style={
            person,
            draw
        },
        man/.style={
            person,
            label={[% 
                person,
                draw, 
                regular polygon, 
                regular polygon sides=3, 
                minimum size=20pt, 
                yshift=-2pt,
                label position=center
            ]},
        },
        level 2/.style={
            sibling distance=1cm
        },
        to sibling/.style={
            level distance=1.5cm,
            edge from parent path={
                let \p1 = ({$(\tikzparentnode.center)!.5!(\tikzchildnode.center)$} -| \tikzparentnode.center),
                    \p2 = (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor),
                    \n1 = { veclen(\x1,\x2) }
                in
                    (\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) --
                    ({$(\tikzparentnode.center)!.5!(\tikzchildnode.center)$} -| \tikzparentnode.center)
                    [rounded corners={(\n1 < 10 ? 0pt : 10pt)}]
                    -| 
                    (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)
            },
            shorten <=2pt
        },
        sibling/.style={
            level distance=.75cm,
            edge from parent path={
                let \p1 = (\tikzparentnode.center),
                    \p2 = (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor),
                    \n1 = { veclen(\x1,\x2) }
                in
                    [rounded corners={(\n1 < 10 ? 0pt : 10pt)}]
                    (\tikzparentnode.center)
                    -| 
                    (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)
            }
        },
        marriage/.style={
            double, 
            double distance=2pt,
            shorten >=2pt,
            shorten <=2pt
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[family tree]

\node (t1) at (-3,0) {} 
    child[sibling] { node[man] {} 
        child[to sibling] { node[woman] {} }
        child[to sibling] { node[man] {} }
    }
    child[sibling] { node[woman] {} 
        child[to sibling] { node[man] (n3) {} }
    }
    child[sibling] { node[woman] (n1) {} };
    
\node (t2) at (3,0) {} 
    child[sibling] { node[man] (n2) {} }
    child[sibling] { node[man] {} 
        child[to sibling] { node[woman] {} }
    }
    child[sibling] { node[woman] {} 
        child[to sibling] { node[man] {} }
    };
    
\node (t3) at ($(n1)!.5!(n2)$) {} 
    child[to sibling] { node[man] {} }
    child[to sibling] { node[woman] {} };

\node[right of=n3, woman] (n4) {};

\draw[marriage] (n1) -- (n2);

\draw[marriage] (n3) -- (n4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]