# How does using \makebox allow arbitrary placement of things on a page?

Tags: positioning, margins, boxes

What is it about using `\makebox` that makes it disregard text body borders / margins, where other boxes respect the margins / text width and friends?

- Allowing images outside of margin
  [Letting graphics overflow over page edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26951/letting-graphics-overflow-over-page-edge)
- Drawing lines across paper
  [Horizontal line spanning the entire document in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/horizontal-line-spanning-the-entire-document-in-latex)
- Aligning things in margin with paragraph start [How can I top align AND left align a box flush with the top of a paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347077/how-can-i-top-align-and-left-align-a-box-flush-with-the-top-of-a-paragraph)

I ask this because it seems like a magic box that you can just throw anything into and do whatever (same with `\parbox`, I suppose). In TikZ, you have to use the `overlay` option. Is it due to something implicit like that?

Comment: With `\makebox` you can specify `[<size>]`, `[<alignment>]`, as well as `{<content>}`.  When the size is specified, the content can spill out the sides, even as TeX thinks of the box as only be of the specified size.  By throwing in clever use of left/center/right alignment, it provides a mechanism for typesetting stuff at distal locations to the "cursor location". Try `\fbox{\makebox[0pt][r]{This appears to the left}}`.  The box shows where TeX imagines the `<content>` to be.

Comment: Roughly equivalent to `\hbox to <width> {\hss <contents> \hss}`.  Core TeX `\hss` is like `\hfill`, only it can shrink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about `\makebox`. If you go

```
\parbox{1cm}{...}
```

then if `...` is wider than 1in you will get an overfull box, but it is possible to make the text visually wider without being wider to tex, eg

`\parbox{1cm}{XXXXXXXXXXX\hspace{-10cm}X}`

is not overfull, despite the fact that the X will extend past the 1cm boundary of the box.

`\makebox` is just a box with (if you use the length option) a specified width but glue added either side that can stretch or shrink an arbitrary amount so that the contents are always exactly the width of the box, even if they appear to extend past it.