# making a table fit on a page by moving it left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, margins

I have a table where the last columns fall off the page. Instead of making the text smaller I would like the table to not adhere to the margin of where it begins. I would like to move it to the left. I am using `flushleft`, which is not working. Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{21}{l}{a)text}\\ \hline
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20\\ \hline
day1&9.2&8.6&8.1&6.3&7.7&7.3&8.0&8.4&5.9&6.8&7.3&7.6&9.0&7.4&6.6&7.0& 5.3&7.0&8.0&5.2\\
day2&6.7&6.9&0&7.0&0&8.1&9.0&6.1&0&6.9&0&7.3&7.8&5.3&0&8.9&0&8.4&8.4&7.5\\
day3&0&5.2&0&0&7.5&0&0&8.2&0&0&5.4&0&0&8.3&0&0&7.7&0&0&7.3
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment}
\end{figure}
```

What can be modified? What possible solutions exist?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use `adjustwidth` from the [`changepage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) which allows you to widen or shorten the page width from the left or the right.

I loaded the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) with `showframe=true` just so that you an see where the page boundaries lie.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{21}{l}{a)text}\\ \hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20\\ \hline
day1&9.2&8.6&8.1&6.3&7.7&7.3&8.0&8.4&5.9&6.8&7.3&7.6&9.0&7.4 &6.6&7.0&5.3&7.0&8.0&5.2\\
day2&6.7&6.9&0&7.0&0&8.1&9.0&6.1&0&6.9&0&7.3&7.8&5.3&0&8.9&0&8.4&8.4&7.5\\
day3&0&5.2&0&0&7.5&0&0&8.2&0&0&5.4&0&0&8.3&0&0&7.7&0&0&7.3
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment}
 \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it works and I turned the flag for the showframe off after the distance for the adjustwidth was found (\usepackage[showframe=false]{geometry})

Comment: This doesn't work well with `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{...}`, but you can either set it to `1.5\textwidth` or something that looks nice instead, or fall back to `tabular` instead. Does adjustwidth offer a better variable for the new width?

Comment: Very good solution thank you but I had a compile error "option clash for package geometry" with the "showframe=true" option on \usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
So i had to get rid of it, and I worked great anyway ! Why was it useful for ?

Comment: I loaded the geometry package with showframe=true just so that you an see where the page boundaries lie.

Answer (score 67):

Easiest way to do achieve it insert an  `\hskip-4.0cm\begin{tabular}`... `\end{figure}`.

The `hskip-4.0cm` will tell LaTeX to move the box left by the amount of 4.0cm.

Comment: Wouldn't `\hspace*{-4cm}` be "more LaTeX"?

Comment: @egreg It is two characters shorter:) I personally don't mind mixing a bit of LaTeX with TeX. In the same way that if I am using a Python library it shouldn't stop me from using the Python primitives. Also `\hskip` will not introduce a `space` if you leave a space after the `4cm` whereas `\hspace*` will.

Comment: I encountered an issue using `\hskip` where it misbehaved for values under 1.6cm, which went away using `\hspace*`.

Comment: It appears, that if one uses `\begin{table} ... \input{tablecontent} ...\end{table}` the `\hspace{-4cm}` has to go into the file of `tablecontent` itself, in order to have effect

Comment: @YiannisLazarides @Dimpl I had the same problem with `\hskip`. Edited answer to use `\hspace*` - hope that's ok.

Comment: `\hskip-4.0cm` worked whereas `\hspace{-4cm}` only moved a single cell in the left-most column.

Comment: The `\hskip` and `hspace` commands did nothing for me, no matter whether placed before `\begin{tabular}`, between it and `\begin{table}` or after `\begin{table}` in the contents of the table.

Comment: What is the difference between `\hspace` and `\hspace*`?

Comment: @Dimpl bless you for the fix for values < 1.6cm. Any idea why <1.6 started causing issues?

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the approach that uses the `adjustwidth` environment to change the width of the text block locally, you can also reduce the amount of inter-column white-space to reduce the overall width of the table and hence make it fit into the normal text block.

Specifically, I recommend that you (i) omit all vertical rules (because they take up some space), (ii) use the `booktabs` package to get well-spaced horizontal rules, and (iii) reduce the amount of inter-column whitespace. The third task may be achieved most easily, in my opinion, by using a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, setting `\tabcolsep` to `0pt`, and using an `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive -- I know, it's not exactly intuitive! -- to make LaTeX figure out how much intercolumn whitespace needs to to be inserted.

As in one of the other answers, I've specified the `showframe=true` option of the `geometry` package merely to show the width of the text block.

[image]

By the way, if one needs to specify that a table should have 21 columns of type `l`, it is not necessary to type

```
\begin{tabular}{ l | l | l | l ... l }
```

Instead, one may specify `\begin{tabular}{ l *{20}{|l} }` to denote 20 instances of "|l". As explained above, I think the table looks just as good -- actually, better :-) -- without any vertical rules, hence my specification `*{21}{l}`. If you simply must have vertical rules after the first column and then after every fifth column, say, you could specify `\begin{tabular}{ l *{4}{|lllll} }`.

Finally, when placing a `tabular` (or `tabular*`) environment in a `float` environment, it's better to use the `table` environment rather than the `figure` environment (as you did in your MWE).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe=true]{geometry} % remove 'showframe' option in real doc.
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out amount of intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{21}{l}} % no vert. bars
\toprule
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\ 
\midrule
Day 1 & 9.2&8.6&8.1&6.3&7.7&7.3&8.0&8.4&5.9&6.8&7.3&7.6&9.0&7.4&6.6&7.0&5.3&7.0&8.0&5.2\\
Day 2 & 6.7&6.9&0&7.0&0&8.1&9.0&6.1&0&6.9&0&7.3&7.8&5.3&0&8.9&0&8.4 &8.4&7.5\\
Day 3 & 0&5.2&0&0&7.5&0&0&8.2&0&0&5.4&0&0&8.3&0&0&7.7&0&0&7.3\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{\label{tab:text}Text Experiment}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

Rather than nudging the table over an arbitrary distance, I'd recommend resizing or centering the table. LaTeX will do the tedious work of figuring out what that distance ought to be to fit the table on the page. The `graphicx` package will enable resizing within a `\figure` or `\table` environment. Simply enclose your `\tabular` or `\includegraphics` with

```
\resizebox{1 \textwidth}{!}{
.
.
}
```

Similarly, `makebox` enables centering of tables and figures:

```
\makebox[1 \textwidth][c]{ 
.
.
}
```

Change the inputs to `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}` as you see fit. Note that these can extend beyond the boundaries of `makebox`. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % enable graphics, images and resizebox

\usepackage{multicol} % enable multicolumn
\usepackage{lipsum}   % generate example text


\begin{document}

\section{Before}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{21}{l}{a)text}\\ \hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20\\ \hline
day1&9.2&8.6&8.1&6.3&7.7&7.3&8.0&8.4&5.9&6.8&7.3&7.6&9.0&7.4&6.6 &7.0&5.3&7.0&8.0&5.2\\
day2&6.7&6.9&0&7.0&0&8.1&9.0&6.1&0&6.9&0&7.3&7.8&5.3&0&8.9&0&8.4&8.4&7.5\\
day3&0&5.2&0&0&7.5&0&0&8.2&0&0&5.4&0&0&8.3&0&0&7.7&0&0&7.3
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment}
\end{figure}


\section{Resize}

\begin{figure}[!h]

\resizebox{1 \textwidth}{!}{   %resize table

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{21}{l}{a)text}\\ \hline
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20\\ \hline
day1&9.2&8.6&8.1&6.3&7.7&7.3&8.0&8.4&5.9&6.8&7.3&7.6&9.0&7.4&6.6 &7.0&5.3&7.0&8.0&5.2\\
day2&6.7&6.9&0&7.0&0&8.1&9.0&6.1&0&6.9&0&7.3&7.8&5.3&0&8.9&0&8.4 &8.4&7.5\\
day3&0&5.2&0&0&7.5&0&0&8.2&0&0&5.4&0&0&8.3&0&0&7.7&0&0&7.3
\end{tabular}

} %close resize


\caption{\label{fig:text2}text experiment}
\end{figure}

\section{Center}

\begin{figure}[!h]


\makebox[1 \textwidth][c]{       %centering table
\resizebox{1.3 \textwidth}{!}{   %resize table

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{21}{l}{a)text}\\ \hline
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20\\ \hline
day1&9.2&8.6&8.1&6.3&7.7&7.3&8.0&8.4&5.9&6.8&7.3&7.6&9.0&7.4&6.6&7.0&5.3&7.0&8.0&5.2\        day2&6.7&6.9&0&7.0&0&8.1&9.0&6.1&0&6.9&0&7.3&7.8&5.3&0&8.9&0&8.4&8.4&7.5\        day3&0&5.2&0&0&7.5&0&0&8.2&0&0&5.4&0&0&8.3&0&0&7.7&0&0&7.3
\end{tabular}

} %close resize
} %close centering


\caption{\label{fig:text3}text experiment}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

This generates the following document with dummy text for comparison with margins.

[image]

Comment: This is the nicest solution of all above, much more general than fixing a dimension with adjustwidth.

Comment: I agree with the previous commenter. This is the one solution that works very nicely and is easy to configure to own needs. Ended up only using the `\resizebox{<size> \textwidth}{!}{ <content> }` part of this solution that worked perfectly for a `landscape` mode `table`.

Answer (score 8):

Simple answer : If you want to shift 6 em to the left you do something like

```
\hspace*{-6em}
\begin{tabular}{ m{5em}  m{14em}  m{17em}  m{4em} }
\hline  
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{Degree/Certificate} & \textbf{Institute} & \textbf{CGPA}
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *adjustwidth* environment from the changepage package to shift your table to the left. This environment allows you to widen or shorten the page width from the left or the right. Here is an example of how you can use it.

Step 1: Use the package

```
\usepackage{changepage}
```

Step 2: Add *\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}* after starting table, and add *\end{adjustwidth}* before the table ends.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{center}
```

That's it. Thumbs up if it helped. Thank You!

Comment: Welcome! The same is suggested in the accepted answer.