# Left align a Table?

Tags: tables

I write a simple table code in LaTeX, but it is aligned in the centre of my page. I want to align the whole table in left position. How is this possible?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{| l |p{1in}|p{1in}| l | l |} 
 \hline
{\bf Examination} & {\bf School/college} & {\bf Board/University} &{\bf Year of passing }& $\%$ \\ \hline
B.Tech& A &B & 2014 &   \\ \hline
Plus Two & Science &  B & & \\ \hline
SSLC & SSLC & B & & \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A suggestion: Please post compilable MWEs (minimum working examples) rather than code snippets. Incidentally, if I expand your code into an MWE -- by prefixing `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}` and affixing `\end{document}`-- I do *not* find the table to be centered, contrary to your claim. (It would appear, though, that the third column is too narrow to container the header (`Board/University`) properly.) Please revise your posting so that it generates the problem behavior you're looking to correct.

Comment: Would this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33345/34618