# Custom margin settings for figure in LaTeX

Tags: floats, margins

I have a fairly large figure in a LaTeX document. This figure is too large for the left and right margin of the document. This results in the figure being placed flush with the left margin, and way beyond the right margin. What I want is to do, is center the figure on the page. Can I do this, e.g. by setting a different left margin for this figure?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

If the figure is e.g. 3 inches too wide, add a negative space of half that before the figure:

```
\hspace*{-1.5in}
\includegraphics{...}
```

Comment: How can this `negative space` approach be used to make use of the space on the right?

Comment: For me, images that are too wide automatically already penetrate the right-side margin.

Answer (score 208):

```
\centerline{\includegraphics{...}}
```

Does this without any hspace trickery.

Comment: Very clean code, and solves the need-more-width-for-my-graph problem, so worth a try!

Comment: Excellent, this solved a whole lot more for me!

Comment: Where have you been all my life. Why have I been struggling with this for years...

Comment: How can I do this in Lyx?

Comment: @becko ERT before the image with `\centerline{`, ERT after the image with `}`.

Comment: But this answer works only if the image should be centered. If you just want to give a small, possibly partly transparent, image a negative margin, the accepted answer is better.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed and is the easiest solution. It also worked on a subfigure containing two figures side-by-side. Yay!

Comment: Thank you! So simple yet so powerful.

Comment: Made my day! :)

Answer (score 23):

The above did not work for me as I wanted the figure wider than the caption.
Also, I think there is a override by the `endfloat` package.

This will leave the entire document intact and only alter the figure:

```
\begin{figure}
    \advance\leftskip-4cm
    \includegraphics[options]{location}
\end{figure}
```

You could also use:

```
\advance\rightskip-2cm
```

Comment: Your code snippet worked just fine, thank you for the insight ! The hspace command above didn't work in my case.

Comment: This worked well for me in the case of multiple horizontally distributed \includegraphics in the same figure :)

Answer (score 16):

If the figure is an external graphics, then do like this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

`\textwidth` will stretch it to full text width. You can specify a coefficient like, for example, `0.75` of the text width:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{...}
```

Answer (score 12):

Found a great simple solution to this problem!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\includegraphics[width=1.4\textwidth]{mypic}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I found this solution here:
http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/centering-figure-table/#comment-875

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the memoir class, the solution is to use

```
\centerfloat
```

rather than

```
\centering
```

in your float. This will prevent you from having to manually set the negative horizontal spacing.

Maybe you're not using memoir. Fair enough. `\centerfloat` is defined thusly, so you can just make your own:

```
\newcommand*{\centerfloat}{%
  \parindent \z@
  \leftskip \z@ \@plus 1fil \@minus \textwidth
  \rightskip\leftskip
  \parfillskip \z@skip}
```

Comment: \centerfloat works great in memoir class

Answer (score 2):

The automated version of Ian's answer might look like this:

```
\newlength{\myimageoversize}
\newsavebox{\myimage}
\newcommand{\mycenter}[1]{%
\savebox{\myimage}{#1}
\settowidth{\myimageoversize}{\usebox{\myimage}}
\addtolength{\myimageoversize}{-\textwidth}
\setlength{\leftskip}{-0.5\myimageoversize}
\noindent
\usebox{\myimage}}

\begin{figure}
\mycenter{\includegraphics{...}}
\end{figure}
```