# Figure fit pagewidth

Tags: subfloats

Since the text in the figures are too small, it's better if I can enlarge them without putting each subfigure on a separate line. I can see only one way to do this is expand the figure to cover the spaces on the left and right side of the figure. Is there any way I can do this ?
Here is the part of the page which contains the figure [image: The figure]
And the code to generate it.

```
\begin{figure*}[!h!t]
\centering

\subfigure[Panda - Week 2]{
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth] {fig/thang_panda2.png}
   \label{fig:esp1_3}
}
\subfigure[Panda - Week 3]{
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth] {fig/thang_panda3.png}
   \label{fig:esp1_4}
}

\subfigure[Penguin - Week 2]{
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth] {fig/thang_penguin2.png}
   \label{fig:esp1_5}
 }
\subfigure[Penguin - Week 3]{
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth] {fig/thang_penguin3.png}
   \label{fig:esp1_6}
}
   \caption{Collaboration using the whiteboard}
   \label{fig:esp1}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to get the figures to expand past the margins, to fill more of the page horizontally?

Comment: If that's the case then davbud's answer on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57702/custom-margin-settings-for-figure-in-latex should do the job

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're using a `twoside` option, so `\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=<len>]{<file>}}` where you specify `<len>` would work. Even if `<len>`>`\textwidth` (say `\paperwidth`, or `1.1\textwidth`, you won't receive any overfull box warnings, since the output is stored in a box of width `\linewidth`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `adjustwidth` environment from the [`changepage`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/changepage) package to help here; the general syntax is

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{<left offset>}{<right offset>}
```

Note that when using it with a `float` (such as `figure`) you have to put it *inside* the `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h!t]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-2cm}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Panda - Week 2]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth] {fig/thang_panda2.png}
        \label{fig:esp1_3}
        }
        \subfloat[Panda - Week 3]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth] {fig/thang_panda3.png}
        \label{fig:esp1_4}
        }

        \subfloat[Penguin - Week 2]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth] {fig/thang_penguin2.png}
        \label{fig:esp1_5}
        }
        \subfloat[Penguin - Week 3]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth] {fig/thang_penguin3.png}
        \label{fig:esp1_6}
        }
        \caption{Collaboration using the whiteboard}
        \label{fig:esp1}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Note also that the [`subfigure`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subfigure) package is considered obsolete (see [What is the difference between \subfigure and \subfloat?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/what-is-the-difference-between-subfigure-and-subfloat)) and you should use [`subfig`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subfig) instead which has the command `subfloat`.

You might also look at the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package- a comparison is made in [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure)