# Figure with two side-by-side subfigures that is wider than textwidth

Tags: margins, subfloats

I have a 2x2 array of subfigures and the ideal size I'd like them at is a bit wider than the textwidth. I saw this solution for a single figure ([Custom margin settings for figure in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57702/custom-margin-settings-for-figure-in-latex)) but am not sure how to adapt it for subfigures.

edit: a 1x2 example of the way I'm building my subfigures

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{6cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{...}
\end{subfigure}
\quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{6cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{...}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a `\makebox` for each row of subfigures (change the lengths to suit your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{image1}
\caption{a test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{image2}
\caption{a test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
}\\
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{image3}
\caption{a test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{image4}
\caption{a test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
}
\caption{A figure with four subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: This also works for forcing subfigures into a certain row of the figure.