# side by side figures wider than margins

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, margins, subfloats

I'm trying to do exactly what's explained here:

[Figure with two side-by-side subfigures that is wider than textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116792/figure-with-two-side-by-side-subfigures-that-is-wider-than-textwidth)

However, I'm working with a large document and already have many subfigures using `\usepackage[hang]{subfigure}`. If I change to the `subcaption` package, I would have to change all my other figures and that's too much work. How do I use the `lipsum` package and `\makebox` command in conjunction with the `subfigure` package?

Answer (score 8):

The techniques explained at the linked answer work with `subfigure` package also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe}   %% remove showframe
\usepackage[hang]{subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\centering
\subfigure[Caption]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\subfigure[Caption]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\subfigure[Caption]{\label{fig:c}\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
}
\caption{my caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `adjustbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.2\linewidth,center}
\centering
\subfigure[Caption]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\subfigure[Caption]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\subfigure[Caption]{\label{fig:c}\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{my caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Here the content will be resized only if it exceeds `1.2\linewidth`. `adjustbox` also provides many other goodies. For details, refer to its documentation.

PS. `subfigure` is deprecated and it is better to change over to `subcation` or `subfig`.

Comment: Is it also possible to add line breaks (`\\ `) between the subfigures inside an `adjustbox`?