# Example images in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics

How to make an example image in LaTeX, a dummy image, a spot holder? I have seen it before, but I can't remember how they would made. It would be nice to be able to use example images - if you should help anyone or you need to question in this community. You might say I could [easily Google it](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=example%20images%20latex), but I tried - and are obviously too stupid to find anything.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[]{}

\begin{document}

\iffalse
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{•} 
\end{figure}
\fi

\end{document}
```

Is it also possible to resize the example image? So I need a usepackage to make an image without including an immage. An placeholder so anyone can try my code without needing images - just needing my tex-code. I hope you understand?

Kind regards!

Comment: Related: [New support package for MWEs](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2470/5764)

Comment: If I google "dummy images latex", I get the mwe package documentation as the 4th result.

Comment: Sounds like you want _placeholder_ images, not examples, right?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Thanks to **Martin Scharrer**, modern LaTeX systems offer you some ready-to-use images; the documentation for the [`mwe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package (Section **4 Provided Images**) describes all available images (initially you had to load to package to use the images, but then the images were made usable without the package):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\qquad
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-golden}\qquad
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}

\noindent\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b} 

\noindent\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-c} 

\noindent\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seams `example-image` stops at `c`. Is it possible to get `example-image-d`?

Comment: @Viesturs There is `example-image-duck` nowadays :)

Answer (score 6):

The documentation folder of PStricks contains some images in a separate folder. Most notably it holds `tiger` (in both EPS and PDF formats):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=150pt]{c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/images/tiger}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen above (under TeX Live 2014 in Windows) it's not that readily accessible.