# "Trimmed" minipage at the end of a column instead of alternate placement

Tags: minipage, multicolumn

I have a 4-column document and what I observed is that when a minipage doesn't fit in the column, then it is "trimmed" instead of being placed in the next column automatically. I thought that when an element in the document doesn't fit in a given vertical space then it is placed in the next page or column and it is not being "trimmed" as it is quite ugly obviously. Why is that happening?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
[   
    landscape,
    top = 0.2in,
    bottom = 0.2in,
    left = 0.2in,
    right = 0.2in,
]{geometry}


\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{4}

\columnseprule = 0.8pt

\vspace*{10cm}

\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-c}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: presumably something in your code is preventing the page break so you get an overfull box and it runs off the page. since you give no clues not really possible to answer what is wrong with the code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't include a MWE because without the images wouldn't compile, but I added one now. As you can see I don't really use anything special in this case. :/

Comment: the images are not relevant to figure positioning you can replace them by `\rule{1cm}{3cm}` or whatever size shows the problem. why have you got the minipages there at all, they don't seem to be doing anything there? but anyway with or without the minipages using multicolumn is making tex work much harder than it needs to compared to just placing the images eg via a table, in the layout you want.

Comment: I tried your code, replaced the images with `example-image-9x16`, and tried to change sizes of images, but no luck in producing your error. The simply go to the next column. Do you get any warnings?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is just a MWE. My real document has two minipages side by side. The first has the image and the one next to it has text.

Comment: @runartrollet No I don't get any warnings or errors.

Comment: could you make an MWE that which compiles and highlights your problem? Instead of your images, use any of the example-images. These all available to all, so it will work for us too. You can find more info about the in Gonzalo Medina's answer in [Example images in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231741/89976)

Comment: @Adam without an example that shows the problem, can't really debug

Comment: @runartrollet I didn't know about those images, thanks! I uploaded a MWE that can be compiled and I updated the picture depicting my problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand, that is why I updated my post. I didn't know that I could use those images to create a MWE that can be compiled.

Comment: Your MWE doesn't produce the same output here it seems. No trimming of images.

Comment: @runartrollet I am using ShareLaTeX if this helps.

Comment: on sharelatex everything looks good. I did switch to the compiler XeLaTex. Also, try downloading the output-`.pdf` from sharelatex, in case it is something wrong with your browser not being able to display the whole page.

Comment: @runartrollet I just did that and the pdf is still trimming. I uploaded my whole code, it is not like I created that MWE and then I produced the picture with another. :/