# (not only) beamer: Automatically Attach Graphic Files (to the PDF Output) that are Used in \includegraphics Command

Tags: beamer, graphics, attachfile

- I like to attach the graphic files that I use in a `beamer` presentation to the generated pdf file.
- The background is, that I want to enable my colleagues at work to be able to use the graphic files e. g. in PowerPoint (I am the only one using LaTeX at work).
- I can attach the graphic files using the `attachfile` package.

> Is there a way to automatize this, so that every `\includegraphics` automatically embeds/attaches the used graphic file?
>
> It would be perfect if I still can use the `\includegraphics` command **unchanged** so that I can use this with already existing presentations.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\begin{document}

% For example image, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738    

\begin{frame}[c]
\frametitle{Frame With Image}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png} 
\textattachfile{example-image.png}{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to generate

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png} 
\textattachfile{example-image.png}{}
```

for each image the simplest would be to use

```
\xgr[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png}
```

with `\xgr` defined in your preamble by

```
\newcommand\xgr[1][]{%
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \textattachfile{#2}{}}
```

If you want to use `\includegraphics` (and better as it allows includegraphics to find the real filename if you omit the extension) use

```
\makeatletter
\let\saved@Gin@setfile\Gin@setfile
\def\Gin@setfile#1#2#3{%
\saved@Gin@setfile{#1}{#2}{#3}%
\textattachfile{#3}{}}
\makeatother
```

`\Gin@setfile` is the last "common" macro in the `\includegraphics` internals which is called after it has resolved any missing extension and looked up the file on the graphics path. it then calls driver-specific code that is different fro pdftex or latex/dvips etc to actually include the image.

`#3` is the full filename with extension,

`#1` is the "file type" (which determines which internal inclusion macros will be used, typically `eps` or `pdf` or some name representing bitmap types, details depend on the driver and which file types it supports,

`#2` is the "read file" such as `example-image.bb` used to find size information from bitmap files, mostly.

So the above just adds a call to attachfile to attach `#3`.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't clear enough. It would be perfect if I still can use the `includegraphics` command unchanged so that I can use this with already existing presentations.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner try now

Comment: Wow - works perfectly in the MWE. It would be great if you could elaborate a bit what you have done (I accept the answer anyway of course). It looks to the untrained eye that you changed some internal commands from the `graphicx` package?!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner well yes but it's my code so doesn't feel that "internal" to me:-) I'll add some words

Comment: I did not notice that until now - well apparently your packages are legion :) (https://www.ctan.org/author/carlisle)