# Automatically Attach Graphic Files (to the PDF Output) that are Used in \includegraphics Command With Options

Tags: graphics

> This is a follow-up question to [(not only) beamer: Automatically Attach Graphic Files (to the PDF Output) that are Used in \includegraphics Command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348827) answered beautifully by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle).

### 1st Question Block

1. I would like to attach a text file with the same file name (and same destination) as the picture that contains the source for example.
2. It would be perfect if this could be "missing file tolerant" (only attach the text file if it's avaialble).

Here's a pseudocode for that:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png} 
\textattachfile{example-image.png}{}
% If possible
\textattachfile{example-image.txt}{} % <-- Text file containing the source for example.
```

### 2nd Question Block

1. Is there a way to have an additional option in the `\includegraphics` command like `myAttach=false` so that I can deactivate the attaching for specific pictures?
2. Default (no option given) should be that the picture and the text file are attached.

Here's a pseudocode for that:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, myAttach = false]{example-image.png}
% If "myAttach = false" is not mentioned
\textattachfile{example-image.png}{}
% If possible AND if "myAttach = false" is not mentioned
\textattachfile{example-image.txt}{} % <-- Text file containing the source for example.
```

### MWE so far (result from previous question)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\makeatletter
\let\saved@Gin@setfile\Gin@setfile
\def\Gin@setfile#1#2#3{%
\saved@Gin@setfile{#1}{#2}{#3}%
\textattachfile{#3}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% For example image, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738    

\begin{frame}[c]
\frametitle{Frame With Image}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png} 
\textattachfile{example-image.png}{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\makeatletter
\let\saved@Gin@setfile\Gin@setfile

\def\Gin@setfile#1#2#3{%
\saved@Gin@setfile{#1}{#2}{#3}%
\ifGin@attach
\textattachfile{#3}{}%
{\def\Gin@ext{.txt}%
\IfFileExists{#3}{%
\textattachfile{#3}{}%
}{\PackageWarning{graphicx}{no #3 to attach}}%
}%
\fi
}
\newif\ifGin@attach\Gin@attachtrue
\define@key{Gin}{attach}[true]{%
  \lowercase{\Gin@boolkey{#1}}{attach}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

% For example image, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738    

\begin{frame}[c]
\frametitle{Frame With Image}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.png} 
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a.png} 
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,attach=false]{example-image-b.png} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Example where only `example-image-a.txt` was available.)

Comment: Works perfectly! The feature with including a text file (if available) is not implemented yet. Are you also trying to achieve it?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner try now

Comment: Great! I modified the example and added a screenshot - hope that's ok!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner sure :-)

Comment: I encountered a problem when I also use the package `pdfpages`. I cannot include a pdf -- it looks like that is somehow also sees the new option `attach` and that it doesn't "like" it. Should i open a new question?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner possibly a new question but answer is likely to just wrap the  pdfpages include by a local `\let\Gin@setfile\saved@Gin@setfile` to put the original definition back

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not understand LaTeX enough :). Where do I put the code you recommended (`\let\Gin@setfile\saved@Gin@setfile`)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner inside your makeatletter area define `\newcommand\mypdfpages[2][]{{\let\Gin@setfile\saved@Gin@setfile\pdfpages[#1]{#2}}}` then use `\mypdfpages` probably works (untested:-)