# How to use variable for \includegraphics and \attachfile in LaTeX3

Tags: graphics, expl3, latex3, attachfile

I want make a function, it can insert image and attach file (e.g., the data about plotting), so I need set a variable for image name and it will use for attachfile.(`\attachfile` from `attachfile2` package.)

But now I don't know how to use variable for `\includegraphics` and `\attachfile` in LaTeX3.

(I ignored `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` in below code.)

## Question 1: `\includegraphics`

Variable for LaTeX2e is fine.

```
\def\imgname{img.eps}
\includegraphics{\imgname}
```

But LaTeX3 failed:

```
\tl_new:N \l_img_name_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_img_name_tl {example-image.eps} 
\includegraphics{\tl_use:N \l_img_name_tl}
```

Successful only when I use "example-image" (no extension), but I want keep extension for select different file which has same name (img.eps, img.png, ....), so I tried another variable for extension but failed also.

```
\tl_new:N \l_img_name_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_img_name_tl {example-image} 
\tl_new:N \l_ext_name_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_ext_name_tl {eps}
\includegraphics{\tl_use:N \l_img_name_tl . \tl_use:N \l_ext_name_tl}
```

(Update: I discover above code only failed in eps, it work fine in pdf, png, jpg. And `\tl_use:N` may not required, I am not sure.)

## Question 2: `\attachfile`

LaTeX2e failed also:

```
\def\fname{test.txt}
\attachfile{\fname}
```

Look like `\attachfile` will not expand any macro. So I define command to fix, Do you have any ideal better than this ? (Below code is LaTeX3)

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\eftaf}{m}{ % expand filename to \textattachfile
    \attachfile{#1}
}
\eftaf{\tl_to_str:N \l_data_fullname_tl}
```

## Question 3: dot in file name

I know when filename include dot, we should use `{}`. ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10575/111676))

```
\includegraphics{{img.img}.eps}
```

Do we have better method to solve this problem in LaTeX3? For example use `str` type for image name without extension. (And It will split from name with extension.)

Update, because I can use `\includegraphics` by variable now.`str` type can work fine. Below is code:

```
\tl_new:N \l_img_name_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_img_name_tl {img.img} 
\tl_new:N \l_ext_name_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_ext_name_tl {pdf} 
\includegraphics{\tl_to_str:N \l_img_name_tl . \l_ext_name_tl}
```

But `\l_img_name_tl` can not use {{img.img}}, any ideal for expand this?

Comment: The problem with multiple dots in a graphics file name is solved by package `grffile`.

Comment: The file name parser that is used by package `graphics` requires that the extension is not hidden inside a macro. Only a macro at the start of the image file name is expanded once.

Comment: Maybe related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350258