# \includegraphics does not find picture if passed as variable

Tags: latex3, includegraphics

I want to import a picture by passing a variable which stores its name instead of the name itself. Here is example code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\varpicture}{
    \tl_new:N \l_img_name_tl
    \tl_set:Nn \l_img_name_tl {uniquename.png}
    \node (p) at (0,0) {
        \includegraphics[width=100pt]{uniquename.png} %works
        \includegraphics[width=100pt]{\tl_use:N \l_img_name_tl} %doesn't work
    };  
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \varpicture
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Only resource that I found regarding this issue is here: [How to use variable for \includegraphics and \attachfile in LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361363/how-to-use-variable-for-includegraphics-and-attachfile-in-latex3)

If I try to rename the file such that it is called: "uniquename" instead of "uniquename.png" I get the same error, which is that the file cannot be found. None of the solutions used in the other thread work for me.

I compile TeX code with "pdflatex".

Comment: Just remove the `\tl_use:N` and use `\l_img_name_tl` directly.

Comment: works fine for me. Is your system up-to-date? And is `uniquename` really the name you are trying to use? Side remark: move the `\tl_new:N` outside your command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A macro at the start of the file name would be expanded *once* in `\includegraphics` (as stated by [@HeikoOberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361363/how-to-use-variable-for-includegraphics-and-attachfile-in-latex3#comment891038_361363)).

A `tl` variable can be expected to expand to its contents in one expansion step, so you can drop the `\tl_use:N` (which needs more than one step) at the beginning and directly use `\l_img_name_tl`. On recent installations the variant with `\tl_use:N` would work as well (as also mentioned by [@UlrikeFischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576950/includegraphics-does-not-find-picture-if-passed-as-variable/576953#comment1452547_576950))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_img_name_tl

\newcommand{\varpicture}{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_img_name_tl {example-image-duck.pdf}
    \node (p) at (0,0) {
        \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-duck.pdf} %works
        \includegraphics[width=100pt]{\l_img_name_tl}
    };  
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \varpicture
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]