# includegraphics with subfloats and vrules: vrule not even

Tags: subfloats

I would like to position some grafics in an special order and layout. I try to seperate one "column" using `vrule`

as you can see here, the vrule is not aligned on both positions, but for me the `width` settings of both "rows" looks like the same.

[image: not aligned]

here is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [h]
  \centering\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{a}
  \subfloat[A Text]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image}}
  \hspace{0.03\textwidth} \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{b}
  \subfloat[B Text]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image}}
  \hspace{0.03\textwidth} \vrule\ \hspace{0.015\textwidth} \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{e} 
  \subfloat[E Text]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image}}

     \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{c}
  \subfloat[C Text]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image}}
  \hspace{0.03\textwidth}\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{d}
  \subfloat[D Text]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image}}
  \hspace{0.03\textwidth} \vrule\ \hspace{0.015\textwidth} \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{f} 
  \subfloat[F Text]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image}}

  \captionof{figure}[]{A-F Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

any suggestions why it is not aligned?

Comment: It would be much easier to debug if you provided a test document that demonstrated the issue. You can use `example-image` as the image, which is in distributions for that use.

Comment: Addition to @DavidCarlisle 's comment. See here for pre-installed **example images**: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738/

Comment: The code is not compilable because it's a fragment only

Comment: I changed it to `example-image`

Comment: @user2798895: Yes, but it's no document we can compile

Comment: Remove the space in `\hspace{0.03\textwidth} \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{b}`, i.e.: `\hspace{0.03\textwidth}\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{b}`

Comment: I added the missing lines. now you should be able to compile

Comment: @esdd: ahh ok thats it, in line "B" is one space to much. Removing this helps. thx

Comment: Why `\captionof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care to not insert unwanted spaces in your code. They where the reason for the wrong alignment. I inserted some % to ensure that there are non at the end of each line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [h]

\centering\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{a}%
\subfloat[A Text]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]%
    {example-image}}%
\hspace{0.03\textwidth}\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{b}%
\subfloat[B Text]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]%
    {example-image}}%
\hspace{0.03\textwidth}\vrule\
\hspace{0.015\textwidth}\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{e}%
\subfloat[E Text]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]%
    {example-image}}%

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{c}%
\subfloat[C Text]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]%
    {example-image}}%
\hspace{0.03\textwidth}\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{d}%
\subfloat[D Text]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]%
    {example-image}}%
\hspace{0.03\textwidth}\vrule\
\hspace{0.015\textwidth}\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{f}%
\subfloat[F Text]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]%
    {example-image}}%

\captionof{figure}[]{A-F Text}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I think an easier solution would be to use a tabular to take care of the alignment, spacing and vertical rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [h]

\begin{tabular}{c c | c}
    \subfloat[A Text]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}} &
    \subfloat[B Text]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}} &
    \subfloat[C Text]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}} \\
    \subfloat[D Text]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}} &
    \subfloat[E Text]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}} &
    \subfloat[F Text]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}} \\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{figure}[]{A-F Text}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different approach, similar to Georg's, but that avoids the need of juggling with counters.

Nesting tabulars will ensure correct numbering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp] % <--- not only h
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\subfloat[A Text]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}%
}
&
\subfloat[B Text]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}%
}
\\
\subfloat[C Text]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}%
}
&
\subfloat[D Text]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}%
}
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\subfloat[E Text]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}%
}
\\
\subfloat[F Text]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}%
}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\caption{A-F Text}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]