# Organizing Title Page

Tags: titles, logos, organisation

Good Morning everyone. 
I am working on the title page of my thesis and since I am totally new in Latex I'm having some problem that I guess I am not able to fix.

From this code my purpose is to have a good symmetry between the two logos that I would like to be on the same line withe the two text precisely under each of them.

Then I would like the text "" little bit close to the center in respect to the left margin and to be at almost the half of the page.

Lastly I would like to put a straight line just over the date and the academic year (pushing them on the bottom of the page) in order to keep the symmetry with the top of the page.

I guess are not so difficult things but you have to know the right commands to do them, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bm} % {\bm ... } 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}  % textblock
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\xx}{ {\bm x } }

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm}}
\center
\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(8cm,0.5cm)
    \centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo2.png}
\end{textblock*}

\textsc{\LARGE Università degli Studi di Torino}\\[0.2cm] % Name of your university/college

\HRule \\[0.5cm]

\textsc{\Large Tesi di Laurea Magistrale in\\ Fisica dei Sistemi Complessi}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large Dipartimento di Fisica}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Master Thesis}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule 

\begin{textblock*}{7cm}(1cm,13cm)
        \begin{flushleft}
            \includegraphics[width=7cm]{Nordita_logo.pdf}\\[1.1cm]
    \textbf{\emph{Supervisor at Nordita:} \\
        Prof. Ralf \textsc{Eichhorn} }
    \end{flushleft}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(15cm,13cm)
    \begin{flushleft}
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo1.png}
        \textbf{\emph{Supervisor at Turin University:}\\
            Miguel \textsc{Onorato} }
    \end{flushleft}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(1cm,17cm)
    \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{\emph{Candidato:}
            Kim \textsc{Nicoli} }\\
            \textbf{\emph{Matricola:}
             \textsc{766461} }\\
    \end{flushleft}
\end{textblock*}

\vspace{12cm}

\thispagestyle{empty}

%\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace
{\large \today}\\
{\large Anno Accademico 2016-2017}



\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe it'd be good that you substitute each `*.png` file with `example-image-a` (this example image and others are provided by the `graphicx` package) and set both `width` and `height` appropriately, so that we can emulate exactly what you've done.

Comment: As a personal side note I wouldn't exaggerate with horizontal lines: there are three of them already, do you really want to add one more? I'd rather remove some of them! I suggest that you have a look at the documentation of [geometry](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) and, if you're italian too, at [ArteLaTeX](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/ArteLaTeX.pdf), if you haven't done yet.

Comment: Remove the horizontal lines. At one point in the past, someone presented an example titlepage he deemed nice and that spread and everybody continued with the lines and spread it further. There is no need to use lines to draw any attention.

Comment: Having said that, what wikibook did you get that from?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [how to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280). That should fix most of your problems.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis To be precise, those images are provided by the [`mwe`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package, but you don't need to have `\usepackage{mwe}` in a document to use them.

Comment: Oh, thank you for correcting, [you're right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231741/87996).

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples/blob/master/badger.png

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I had in mind even if is without horizontal lines. It looks even better actually...
Thanks again

Comment: @Johannes_B Would you post an answer or should we close the question?

Comment: @carlatex we could close as duplicate.