# How to preserve a space for a figure to be added later?

Tags: graphics, floats

I want to add an empty figure in a document with added captions .. etc, so that I can add the figures later. Is there a direct way to do this? For example insert a white box with a big X across it or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Based on [Example images in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738).
- The MWE package provides example pictures.
- Another possibility is the `demo` option of the `graphicx` package which includes a black square.
- I prefer ways that use the 'normal' `\includegraphics` command since it means less change when you include the actual content later. On the other hand, the `\missingfigure` command in the other answer shows very clear that something has to be done (which is good depending on the use case).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

Text before.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=50mm,height=20mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

Text after.

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

Text before.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=150mm,height=20mm]{}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

Text after.

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Don't use `[H]`, please!

Comment: @egreg Haha -- I will not argue with you!

Answer (score 4):

A couple of other ways.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
% \missingfigure is from todonotes
\missingfigure[figwidth=\linewidth,figcolor=white]{Some text if needed}
\caption{Bla}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\framebox[7cm]{\scalebox{15}{X}}
\caption{Bla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice alternatives!