# How to include image, \caption and center the content of a table

Tags: tables, graphics, captions, multirow

I'm doing a table with images, and I would like to include the caption for each image and also I would like to align the rows.[image]

```
\begin{table}  [ht]
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{||c c c c ||} 
    \toprule 
 Sample number & Dimensions & Result & Observations \\ [0.5ex] 
 \midrule
 H1E & $T:29.37\pm0.01$ mm &
 \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{h1e.jpg}} &
 Valid test\\
 &  $L:29.00\pm0.01$ mm &  &   \\
 & W:$33.90\pm0.01$ mm & & \\
 \hline
  H2E & $T:29.40\pm0.01$ mm &
 \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{h2e.jpg}} &
 Invalid test, no parallelism\\
 &  $L:28.50\pm0.01$ mm &  &   \\
 & W:$34.41\pm0.01$ mm & & \\
 \hline
  H3E & $T:29.17\pm0.01$ mm &
 \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{h3e.jpg}} &
 Valid test\\
 &  $L:27.50\pm0.01$ mm &  &   \\
 & W:$30.39\pm0.01$ mm & & \\
 \hline
  H4E & $T:30.55\pm0.01$ mm &
 \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{h4e.jpg}} &
 Valid test\\
 &  $L:29.94\pm0.01$ mm &  &   \\
 & W:$31.70\pm0.01$ mm & & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Static compression tests in axial direction of honeycomb}
  \label{tab:statcomp}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you have so far? This will help us help you.  Also, we do not have your images available.  Please consider providing them, or using [example images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738/example-images-in-latex).

Comment: Out of topic: I suggest you to have a look at the [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package. You might want to redesign your table according to best practices detailed in its documentation.

Comment: Can you mention the packages you have used @Mark Spring

Comment: @Biki Teron. I don't really know because I have a template from the Institute, but I have also included \usepackage{multirow, array}. That's the first time I use TeX...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main challenges are the `Dimensions` and the `Result` columns. I suggest using a `p` column for the `Dimensions` to wrap all three lines into one cell. For the `Result` column, the `valign=m` option from the `adjustbox` package can be used. Finally, the inner `\hline`s should all be replaced by `\midrule`s for consistency.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, array, booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{cm{.25\textwidth}cc} 
 \toprule 
 Sample number & Dimensions & Result & Observations \\ \midrule
 H1E & $T:29.37\pm0.01$ mm \newline
       $L:29.00\pm0.01$ mm \newline
       W:$33.90\pm0.01$ mm &
 \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,valign=m]{h1e.jpg} &
 Valid test \\ \midrule
 %
 H2E & $T:29.40\pm0.01$ mm \newline
       $L:28.50\pm0.01$ mm \newline
       W:$34.41\pm0.01$ mm &
 \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,valign=m]{h2e.jpg} &
 Invalid test, no parallelism \\ \midrule
 %
 H3E & $T:29.17\pm0.01$ mm \newline 
       $L:27.50\pm0.01$ mm \newline
       W:$30.39\pm0.01$ mm &
 \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,valign=m]{h3e.jpg} &
 Valid test\\ \midrule
 % 
 H4E & $T:30.55\pm0.01$ mm \newline
       $L:29.94\pm0.01$ mm \newline
       W:$31.70\pm0.01$ mm &
 \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,valign=m]{h4e.jpg} &
 Valid test \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Static compression tests in axial direction of honeycomb}
\label{tab:statcomp}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two layouts, with captions,. One uses `makecell` only for padding and line breaks in cells and `hhline`, the other uses  `tabstackengine` for another alignment of dimensions, which are grouped in a single cell in both cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, caption, hhline}
\captionsetup{font =footnotesize, skip=6pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [!ht]
 \centering%
 \renewcommand{\cellalign}{lt}
 \setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells
 \setstackgap{L}{3.5ex}
  \begin{tabular}{||c >{\stackMath}ccc ||}
    \hhline{----}
 \makecell{Sample\\ number} & Dimensions (mm)& Result & Observations \\ [0.5ex]
    \hhline{||----||}
 H1E & {$\tabbedLongunderstack[l]{%
 T: & 29.37\pm0.01\\ L: & 29.00\pm0.01\\ W: & 33.90\pm0.01}$} &
 \raisebox{\dimexpr 1.6ex-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{vent_cat}} &
 Valid test\\
    \hhline{||----||}
  H2E &%
{$\tabbedLongunderstack[l]{%
T: & 29.40\pm0.01 \\ L: & 28.50\pm0.01 \\ W: & 34.41\pm0.01}$} &
 \raisebox{\dimexpr 2ex-\height}{\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{vent_cat}%\\
 \centering\captionof{figure}{\\Ventriloquist Cat}}} &
 Invalid test, no parallelism\\
    \hhline{||----||}
  H3E & {$\tabbedLongunderstack[l]{T: & 29.17\pm0.01 \\ L: & 27.50\pm0.01 \\ W: & 30.39\pm0.01}$} &
 \raisebox{\dimexpr 2ex-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{vent_cat}} &
 Valid test\\%
    \hhline{||----||}
  H4E & {$\tabbedLongunderstack[l]{T: &30.55\pm0.01 \\ L: &\phantom{0}9.94 \pm0.01 \\ W:&31.70\pm0.01 }$} &
 \raisebox{\dimexpr 2ex-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{vent_cat}} &
 Valid test\\
    \hhline{----}
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Static compression tests in axial direction of honeycomb}
  \label{tab:statcomp}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [!ht]
 \centering%
 \renewcommand{\cellalign}{lt}
 \setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells
 \begin{tabular}{c >{$}c<{$}cc}
 \toprule
 \makecell{Sample \\ number} & \text{Dimensions (mm)} & Result & Observations \\ [0.5ex]
 \midrule
 H1E & \makecell{T: 29.37\pm0.01\\ L: 29.00\pm0.01\\ W: 33.90\pm0.01} &
 \raisebox{\dimexpr 2ex-\height}{\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{\centering\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{sendak}\captionof{figure}{Where the Wild Things are}}} &
 Valid test\\
 \addlinespace[3ex]
 H2E & \makecell{T: 29.40\pm0.01 \\ L: 28.50\pm0.01 \\ W: 34.41\pm0.01} &
 \raisebox{\dimexpr 2ex-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{sendak}} &
 Invalid test, no parallelism\\
 \addlinespace[3ex]
 H3E & \makecell{T: 29.17\pm0.01 \\ L: 27.50\pm0.01 \\ W: 30.39\pm0.01} &
 \raisebox{\dimexpr 2ex-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{sendak}} &
 Valid test\\%
 \addlinespace[3ex]
 H4E & \makecell{T: 30.55\pm0.01 \\ L: 9.94\pm0.01 \\ W: 31.70\pm0.01 } &
 \raisebox{\dimexpr 2ex-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{sendak}} &
 Valid test\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \caption{Static compression tests in axial direction of honeycomb}
 \label{tab:statcomp-1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]