# Catalogue of example images

Tags: graphics

I use Ubuntu and TeXLive. When asking a question one is requested to provide an MWE. Sometimes an MWE needs to include an image, which should then be available to anyone who wants to process the MWE. I do not want to make some of my images generally available, e.g., for copyright reasons. By searching back through old questions I found that an image called `example-image` seemed to be generally available in TeXLive. I also recall seeing a `tiger` image somewhere or other (try `texdoc tiger`) but when I tried to include it in a draft MWE I got an error saying `file not found`. Is there any list/catalogue of images that could be used in an MWE that any TeXLive (or other) distribution would provide.

What I, and I assume others, would like to do is:

```
\includegraphics[...]{IMAGE}
```

where `IMAGE` is generally available, but could be one of a variety of images. My latest MWE would ideally include 12 different images but only uses one.

Comment: `example-image` is from the `mwe` package, which makes minimal examples easier to construct.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Example images in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231738/5764)

Comment: You either have to have the [`mwe` package](//ctan.org/pkg/mwe) installed to have access to `example-image` (and the like), but you don't have to add `\usepackage{mwe}` to your preamble. Most people probably install the entire TeX Live, which would include `mwe`.

Comment: you can use example-image, example-image-a, example-image-b (and a few others) but also most questions are about positioning of the image in which case you don't need an image at all you can use `\rule{3cm}{2cm}` or whatever size you need to make something with the same positioning logic but no dependencies