# LaTeX floats controls don't work

Tags: floats, positioning

Tables, graphs and images don't show up at the same position it was inserted in the TeX file. I tried to suppress floating by using:

```
\usepackage{float}
...
\begin{figure}[H] {15cm}
\caption{}%
\label{}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{image.jpeg}}
\end{figure}
```

also

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp] {15 cm}
...

\usepackage{placeins}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[H] {15cm}
...
```

but these commands keep insisting on moving figures, tables and graphs to unexpected locations. I'm using repUERJ template available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bpqdkmgxznvh#/11388571/)

Does anyone know why it happens?

Comment: `\FloatBarrier` has to go after the figure to prevent the figure from being placed after that point

Comment: `H` is almost always a guarantee for bad placement

Comment: also `\begin{figure}[H] {15cm}` would just write `15cm` in to the output, if you have loaded the float package `[H]` will never float from the source position. (if you have not loaded float then `[H]` should give an error unless you have an old latex (when it will force the float to the end of the document)

Comment: If you need specific help you should always provide a small complete test example that can be run to debug the problem.

Comment: also of course you can just use `\includegraphics` the reason to use `figure` is to mark the content as being not in the main document flow and can be moved to help with page breaking, so it not being output at that position isn't a problem, it is the main purpose of the environment.

Comment: As David just mentioned, to avoid floating, avoid the `figure` environment.

Comment: Using just `\includegraphics` does not work for me. I need to arrange my images in a list of images, therefore `\label`, `\caption` and `\source` are important.

Comment: Maybe provide a full MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) and use example images (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738) and make clear what your desired output should look like. The `\source` command (mentioned in one of your comments) is not known to me. Maybe it's defined in the `repUERJ` document class that you are referring to.

Comment: @samcarter, it's a legacy default behavior for word processor users: "I want it here because I want it and that's where I want it. Period".