# different page geometry for image

Tags: graphics, geometry

I am writting in latex I have very thin page style (I want to keep it that way) but I have very wide image

How do I change geometry for image only not text

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage[pdftex,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing  
%\doublespacing


\geometry{includefoot, left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=2cm\indent}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\EX}{\mathbb{E}}% expected value
%\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}
%\linespread{1.25}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\title{Time Series (Kevin Kotze)}
\author{Petr Hrobař}
\date{ }
\maketitle
\section{Moving average models (MA)}
Moving average process (MA) is defined by this equation:
\begin{equation}
y_{t} = \mu + \epsilon_{t} + \theta\epsilon_{t-1}    
\end{equation} 

where {$\mu$} is a constant, weighted sum of constants is represented by {$y_{t}$}, and the two latest values of {$\epsilon_{t}$} and {$\epsilon_{t-1}$} are both assumed to be independent and identically distributed white noise ${\epsilon_{t}} \sim N($0$, \sigma^{2}$). 

Suppose that MA(1) process is \textit{stationary}, to proof that we need to calculate the different moments of the process. The mean (the first moment) of the process can be calculated as follows:
\begin{equation}
\EX[y_{t}] = \EX[\mu + \epsilon_{t} + \theta\epsilon_{t-1}]
= \mu + \EX[\epsilon_{t}] + \theta\EX[\epsilon_{t-1}] = \mu
\end{equation}

Since ${\epsilon_{t}}$ is assumed to have ${\EX(0|\textbf{x})}$ we can easily obtain that mean is equal to $\mu$.

Second moment (variance) is then given by:
\begin{equation}
    \textbf{var}[y_{t}] = \EX\big[y_{t} - \EX[y_{t}]\big]^{2} = \EX\big[(\mu + \epsilon_{t} + \theta\epsilon_{t-1}) - \mu\big]^{2}\\
 & \ =\EX[\epsilon_{t}]^{2} + 2\theta\EX[\epsilon_{t}\epsilon_{t-1}] + \EX[\theta\epsilon_{t-1}]^{2} = \sigma^{2} + 0 + \theta\sigma^{2} = 
\end{equation}




\clearpage
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{03.pdf}
    \caption{Histogram vysvětlované proměnné \textit{modelu II}}
    \label{histogramyvysvet}
\end{figure}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PRO VLOZENI CITACI A REFERENCI
%\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\newpage
\bibliography{liter}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\includegraphicswidth=1.2\textwidth]{03.pdf}`

Comment: Next time you can use `example-image` to make a code example that can be compiled by others, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738.

Comment: `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{example-image}}`

Comment: Thank you very mutch - it is working now

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell LaTeX to place an extra wide image into a box that is the size of `\textwidth` with a `\makebox`.  It will be centered in the box and spill out to the left and right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{example-image}}
\caption{This is my caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]