# Wrapfig environment doesn't wrap

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Fuh.png]

[image]

My image is leaving a gap through the whole page, here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\fixedalign{\hspace{0.5\linewidth} & \hspace{0.5\linewidth} \nonumber \\[-\baselineskip]}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{examples-examples.jpg}
    \label{fig:example_graph}
    \caption{dfxdxkjfrgbdxjhb  guijchbg jrcb g dxhjgmhbjfbgdm xg dxjgbjmdxbx jgexmdgjx ymgsjdxuygh esjdrg ddjshx ujsegyrj hgxddj ghsmdx djx ygsjdxy gmesjy gaku esr aeyr aerhkjaekrit iea urhuarhku}
\end{wrapfigure}
\subsection*{hjbmbjbjj kiihiki,l}
\subsubsection*{iiihkihuhi 827883} % make a command
kbhhfj:
$$3233 31 4 331 32  2313$$

zxdfg, ahgvcsgdc 3 gyg uu tgff jkfddvfxjn,d xfk j kjfskjsbkfdjdbs z bj sfkjzkdnkzjjn k zj ks  form fhddz hbdjazs,bhszzszj

\begin{align*} %\fixedalign
3232434242  3142 4321 14324&31 \\
5353253235 53 & 4353425234234\\
4221244 423421412 4213412 &424421 1212 \\
4421424121423 4123142 &4324424343432432\\
\end{align*}

3241412332 tgfgfd gx nfhfdg gfgfx bgfc gf gfb ccgf cvcbbcvbbcvvbbfrgf fs dg sfgafygagyregryvc craywkcrjscr
$$32413243421 42 42142143 333 3 43 43 3 3$$

\subsubsection*{Example 1.1.2}
rggdd:
$$fgfggfg324342313421$$

\begin{align*}\fixedalign
424224 &234343233 \\
2342414124v  5412412  & 22312332413412 \\
3234342 & 4224142 3241314132  1122121 \\
\end{align*}
32414gd gh g hfgsh ghg shghd sg  asgh g shsg hgh hgfs
sh gshsg  hghsghs 
g shgshhgsgsh tswhhhhhhhhhhhgggggggggggggggggggggggggshfg
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC I've added it

Comment: Well, now remove unnecessary packages in order to get an MWE, read : [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: @AndréC Some of the possibly unnecessary packages are loaded so you can compile some of the math in the document e.g. amssymb an amsmath.

Comment: All right, so that users are only interested in your problem *(and not in insignificant details)*, replace the images with `example images` as explained here: [Example images in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231741/138900)

Comment: @AndréC I tried using blindttext and lipsum but it didn't show my problem so I did it manually and added an example image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important problem is that wrapfig assumes every line, equation, and box takes precisely `\baselineskip` of space.  The easiest solution is to manually adjust the optional argument of wrapfigure to fit the text.  The second problem is that `\@afterheading` (used by `\section` and `\subsection`) messes with `\everypar`, hense the `\WFclear`.

I replaced some of the random characters so that I could tell whether of not it was working without doing a letter by letter check.  `\label` should go after `\caption`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\fixedalign{\hspace{0.5\linewidth} & \hspace{0.5\linewidth} \nonumber \\[-\baselineskip]}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{R}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Figure capton here.}\label{fig:example_graph}
\end{wrapfigure}
\subsection*{An intelligible strng}
\subsubsection*{Some more identifiable text} % make a command
Start of paragraphe:
$$3233 31 4 331 32  2313$$

\LipsumPar{2}

\WFclear% not sure why this is needed - proabably \@afterheading
\begin{align*} %\fixedalign
3232434242  3142 4321 14324&31 \\
5353253235 53 & 4353425234234\\
4221244 423421412 4213412 &424421 1212 \\
4421424121423 4123142 &4324424343432432\\
\end{align*}

3241412332 tgfgfd gx nfhfdg gfgfx bgfc gf gfb ccgf cvcbbcvbbcvvbbfrgf fs dg sfgafygagyregryvc craywkcrjscr
$$32413243421 42 42142143 333 3 43 43 3 3$$

\subsubsection*{Example 1.1.2}
rggdd:
$$fgfggfg324342313421$$

\begin{align*}\fixedalign
424224 &234343233 \\
2342414124v  5412412  & 22312332413412 \\
3234342 & 4224142 3241314132  1122121 \\
\end{align*}
32414gd gh g hfgsh ghg shghd sg  asgh g shsg hgh hgfs
sh gshsg  hghsghs 
g shgshhgsgsh tswhhhhhhhhhhhgggggggggggggggggggggggggshfg
\end{document}
```