# Set `\fboxsep` only for `\fbox` but not `\boxed`

Tags: fbox

I’m using both `\fbox` and `\boxed` but for different uses. When I use `\fbox`, I need it to have `\fboxsep` set to `-0.5pt`, but when I used `\boxed` I want a `\fboxsep` of `2pt`.

Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: As I was asked for my usage, I defined this in my preamble

```
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}
\setlength\fboxsep{-0.5pt}
\newcommand{\schema}[1]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}}}
```

This is in order to include schemes drawn on a white background in a colored background area (typically one from `tcolorbox`) and have them neatly separated by a thin black margin.

OTOH, I used `\boxed` around all types of mathematical formulas.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of your usage?

Comment: if you set fboxsep negative the left rule will be over-printed by the content and the content will over-print the right rule, but you can define `\myboxxed as {\setlength\fboxsep{2pt}\boxed{#1}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I don’t I get an `Overfull \hbox` instead, because I use `\fbox` around figures that are `\linewidth` wide. See my above edit.

Comment: @Rmano I’m not sure how to do a MWE with images… Is there something like a default random image for that in LaTeX?

Comment: @Archange but that makes no sense you are avoiding a warning by destroying the image, and doing that in an asymmetrical way as on some sides the image will be on top and on others the rule will be on top.

Comment: why not use the standard approach of making the image fit iinside the box? `\noindent\fbox{\gincludegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{...}}`  ???

Comment: @Archange   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231741/38080 - example-image-a etc...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well I’ve never seen any issue with my use, the rule is exactly the same size on all sides. Did not know this was not expected…

Your solution is mostly fine, excepted I don’t want/need `\fboxsep` there because this would now be `0pt` anyway (I need absolutely no space between the figure and the rule). But thanks for this, I’ll adjust my code with it. :)

So my original question is still valid, just replace `-0.5pt` with `0pt` and that’s it. ;)

Comment: setting `\fboxsep` to 0pt is fine but setting it negative does not do anything useful.

Comment: It made a warning go away while providing the output I wanted (in my case at least), so that’s all I cared about. But anyway, I’ve integrated your much better solution now. :)

Comment: 0pt is fine and tested setting for fboxsep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it the other way around:

```
\newcommand{\schema}[1]{%
  \begingroup % localize the changes in the parameters
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-0.5pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}}%
  \endgroup
}
```

This way, any other `\fbox` (and also `\boxed`) will use the default values (or the ones you fix for them).

Comment: Actually this is much cleaner this way, you are right! Merging this with @DavidCarlisle comments on not using a negative `\fboxsep` does exactly what I need everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

With `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass{article} %
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-0.5pt}
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\pretocmd{\boxed}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}}{}{}

\begin{document}

    \[ \boxed{a = \frac{b + c}{2}} \]%

    \centering\fbox{$a = \dfrac{b + c}{2}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...except the default `\fboxsep` is `3pt`, not `2pt`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I know, but the O.P. asked for 2pt in a display style environment,  and -0.5pt  for an ‘ordinary’ \fbox..

Comment: Well, in that case, +1

Comment: @daleif: yes, I guess I was out of my mind.   Fixed. Thank you for warning me!

Comment: This does what the OP asks for, but the correct answer is **DON'T DO THAT!!** `\fbox` with negative `\fboxsep` makes no sense at all.

Comment: @David Carlisle: of course, personally I never do such things, but maybe the O.P. has very good reasons, due to the contents of his \fboxes, to do it?

Comment: @Bernard no it's completely broken, the `\fbox` code was never written to cope with that, it's simpy wrong:-) (not that I blame you for giving what is asked but....)

Answer (score 1):

`\fbox` simply does not work with negative `\fboxsep`  To see what  happens see

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\textcolor{red}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}

\bigskip

\setlength\fboxsep{5pt}

\fbox{\textcolor{red}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}

\bigskip

\setlength\fboxsep{-5pt}

\fbox{\textcolor{red}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}



\end{document}
```

The content over-prints the top and left rule and under-prints the right and bottom.

For the actual use case of boxing an image within `\textwidth` use

```
\noindent\fbox{%
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{example-image}}
```

You could use the above with `\fboxsep` set to 0pt if you want to space.

To get a local setting with boxed, simplest is to define a custom command that locally sets `\fboxsep`

```
\newcommand\myboxed[1]{{{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{2pt}%
     \boxed{#1}}}
```

Comment: This is not exactly related to the question and the original issue still stand (I need to split `boxed` and `fbox` values for `fboxsep`), so it could have stayed in comments above, but thanks anyway. ;)

Comment: @Archange well it's related in that the initial values are wrong. I suppose I could add the comment I made originally that you can define `\myboxed` with a local setting to get a different value there.

Comment: That would be a good idea indeed, and I would right away upvote your answer too in that case. ;) Not that you need the reputation, but heh. ;p

Comment: @Archange clearly I need the rep more than egreg:-) (done:-)