# Plotting functions using domain coloring

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to plot functions using [domain colouring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) that I'd like to combine with `tikz` visual items (like arrows and curves). I've browsed through both `tikz` and `pgfplots` documentations but I could not find any other answer than abusing `\addplot3` command which seems both overkill and super slow (actually the doc itself suggests to refrain from using it for sophisticated plots). The functions I'm dealing with are scalar field over the plane and I *want* a flat 2D representation. Am I missing a more appropriate command? Or by any chance is there some well-known package for this specific purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can use existing diagrams and import them in `pgfplpots`. Then you can use the normal `tikz` commands and `pgfplots` commands to prettify your plot.

> This plot type allows to extend the plotting capabilities of pgfplots
> beyond its own limitations. The idea is to generate the graphics as
> such (for example, a contour plot, a complicated shaded surface9 or a
> large point cluster) with an external program like Matlab or gnuplot.
> The graphics, however, should not contain an axis or descriptions.
> Then, we use \includegraphics and a pgfplots axis which fits exactly
> on top of the imported graphics
>
> *-- Taken from the pgfplots manual: 4.3.7 Using External Graphics as Plot Sources.*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
% See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738 for "example-grid-100x100pt"
% See pgfplots manuel "4.3.7 Using External Graphics as Plot Sources" including "Support for External Three-Dimensional Graphics" 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
axis on top,
]
\addplot graphics [
xmin=-3,xmax=3,
ymin=-3,ymax=3,
] {example-grid-100x100pt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> [image]
> *-- Taken from the `pgfplots` manual.*

Comment: I actually came to the same conclusion that generating my diagrams with an external tool was the best solution.