# Referencing not working properly

Tags: cross-referencing, texstudio

I am new to LaTeX so please excuse my limited knowledge in terminology.

I am working on a project report. I was given a template which uses multiple documents which are then called with `\input` in the main document. I am using TeXstudio so when I open the main document I have access to all called documents. I have noticed a problem.

When I try to reference a figure that was not presented in the same document I can not reference it. I can se the label in the TeXstudio suggestions when I type`\ref{}`. When I build the document I just get `??`

I know that I should add some code, to be more specific but I think I cant recreate the problem with code in this situation

Comment: You need to compile at least twice to have references resolved, unless you're using an automated build process. Have you done that? Also, if the open file (in TeXStudio) is not actually `\input` into the main document, its labels won't be found.

Comment: The file is `\input` into the main document. I have compiled multiple times and it still doesn't work right

Comment: I use TeXstudio and referencing captions from `\input`-ed files work as expected. To recreate the problem, test with an [example-image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231738/140133) and use [filecontents](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/filecontents.pdf).