# Over margin subfigure caption overlay

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to reproduce the example I found here: [Figure with two side-by-side subfigures that is wider than textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116792/figure-with-two-side-by-side-subfigures-that-is-wider-than-textwidth)

I want the same excat thing. 
The issue is that my captions are very extensive. If I do it like in the example my captions start to overlap. Is there a way that I can tell my captions to behave responsible and still extend my images:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}


\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\begin{figure}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.65\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{someImage.png}
\caption{nsdanskdnasndasmnd,asndm,ans,dmndnamsnd,mna,snd,mans,dna,snd,ans,dnalsjdoafmad cknasojnfoansdlknasldnlaksdasdlma snfoojanwdkpmaslmdnakjsbfoasnd askfbaosnfa smf aojsfpasmflamnsfkjbaosfnlaksn f,jasnfohanslfnalsfnpiabsbfouasmfnaösfjkjapwnsdanskdnasndasmnd,asndm,ans,dmndnamsnd,mna,snd,mans,dna,snd,ans,dnalsjdoafmad cknasojnfoansdlknasldnlaksdasdlma snfoojanwdkpmaslmdnakjsbfoasnd askfbaosnfa smf aojsfpasmflamnsfkjbaosfnlaksn f,jasnfohanslfnalsfnpiabsbfouasmfnaösfjkjapw}
\label{SED}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.65\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{someImage.png}
\caption{nsdanskdnasndasmnd,asndm,ans,dmndnamsnd,mna,snd,mans,dna,snd,ans,dnalsjdoafmad cknasojnfoansdlknasldnlaksdasdlma snfoojanwdkpmaslmdnakjsbfoasnd askfbaosnfa smf aojsfpasmflamnsfkjbaosfnlaksn f,jasnfohanslfnalsfnpiabsbfouasmfnaösfjkjapwnsdanskdnasndasmnd,asndm,ans,dmndnamsnd,mna,snd,mans,dna,snd,ans,dnalsjdoafmad cknasojnfoansdlknasldnlaksdasdlma snfoojanwdkpmaslmdnakjsbfoasnd askfbaosnfa smf aojsfpasmflamnsfkjbaosfnlaksn f,jasnfohanslfnalsfnpiabsbfouasmfnaösfjkjapw}
\label{SED1}
\end{subfigure}%
}    
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.65\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{someImage.png}
\caption{asdmlasjkdasdnlansflnalsnflkansflnaslfnlkasnflkansofnaosnfoansofnaosnfoansfonasofnoasnfoqnfonoansifnaisjfnasnfi}
\label{SED2}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.65\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{someImage.png}
\caption{nsdanskdnasndasmnd,asndm,ans,dmndnamsnd,mna,snd,mans,dna,snd,ans,dnalsjdoafmad cknasojnfoansdlknasldnlaksdasdlma snfoojanwdkpmaslmdnakjsbfoasnd askfbaosnfa smf aojsfpasmflamnsfkjbaosfnlaksn f,jasnfohanslfnalsfnpiabsbfouasmfnaösfjkjapw}
\label{SED3}
\end{subfigure}%
}
\caption{
sdamklsadnasld.a,smd.,asm.d,ma.smdaösd.ams.dma.,smd.ams.dmaösmdökams.d,ma.smd.,ams.,d}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

which gives:
[image: overlapping captions]

Comment: Use `\captionsetup` from the `caption` package, as explained in `subcaption`'s manual, to alter the width?

Comment: Great! exactly what I needed.

Comment: Unless you add a few spaces into your random text, LaTeX can't break it.  Also, the paper is only about 4pt wider than the figure.

Comment: Also, you need to add some space between the subfigures to prevent the captions from running into each other.  \hfill won't do anything as there is no space left inside the makebox.  \hspace{\columnsep} would be good, but probably won't fit the page.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Apparently in my first attempt I miss important point: images has to be wider than text width (as noted *John Kormylo in his comment below; thank you John). For this I suggest to use packed `changepage`, which enable to control figure protrusion out of text width separately on both text sides. Answer below is corrected accordingly

I suppose, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

In comparison to your MWE I made the more changes:

- delete `\makebox[\linewidth][c]{% ...}` and replaced with `\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-11mm} ... \end{adjustwidth*}`
- for sub figure width I select `0.48\linetwidth`
- for figures width in `subfigure` I select `\linewidth`
- change `subfigure` position options to `[t]`

For show page layout the package `showframe` is added, in real use it had to be removed.

For text in captions I use dummy text from `lispum` package. Texts in your captions actually is one long word with which LaTeX has trouble to break into more lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text in captions
\usepackage{showframe}% to show page layout

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-11mm}% adjust to desired protrusion into outside margin
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\linewidth}% <-- changed
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{someImage.png}
    \caption{\lipsum*[2]}
\label{SED}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\linewidth}% <-- changed
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{someImage.png}
    \caption{\lipsum*[11]}
\label{SED1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\linewidth}% <-- changed
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{someImage.png}
    \caption{\lipsum*[11]}
\label{SED2}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\linewidth}% <-- changed
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{someImage.png}
    \caption{\lipsum*[3]}
\label{SED3}
    \end{subfigure}%
\caption{The main caption}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe the point was to push into the margins on both sides.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, probably. Apparently this I didn't observe. I change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with both the `\makebox` trick and `changepage` package is that they push symmetrically into the margins, which is fine when the text area is centered in the paper.

The following effects a margin of `\columnsep` at the edge of the paper and between the two subfigures.  For generality I included code for `twoside` documents as well (it may take two runs).

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}% for twoside documents

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text in captions
\usepackage{showframe}% to show page layout

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}
%\null\newpage
\onecolumn
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\tempwidth}{\dimexpr .5\paperwidth-1.5\columnsep}%
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpageoroneside
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\dimexpr \columnsep-1in-\oddsidemargin}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{\dimexpr \columnsep+1in+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth-\paperwidth}%
\else
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\dimexpr \columnsep-1in-\evensidemargin}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{\dimexpr \columnsep+1in+\evensidemargin+\textwidth-\paperwidth}%
\fi
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\tempwidth}% <-- changed
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{someImage.png}
    \caption{\lipsum*[2]}
\label{SED}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\tempwidth}% <-- changed
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{someImage.png}
    \caption{\lipsum*[11]}
\label{SED1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\tempwidth}% <-- changed
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{someImage.png}
    \caption{\lipsum*[11]}
\label{SED2}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\tempwidth}% <-- changed
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{someImage.png}
    \caption{\lipsum*[3]}
\label{SED3}
    \end{subfigure}%
\caption{The main caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```