# subcaption is broken by \makebox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subcaption

I tried following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116795) to get my subfigures to fit ignoring margins, but as soon as I add the `\makebox` call, several errors are returned relating to what look like commands internal to packages at the very least, if not LaTeX internal commands. A simplified case to reproduce this issue is below.

This happens using both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX on Overleaf v2.

### To reproduce the errors with the following example:

Uncomment the `\makebox` line and the closing brace under the last `\end{figure}`

### Errors:

```
! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
\caption@hrule ->\hrule 
                        \@height \z@ 
l.36 }

To put a horizontal rule in an hbox or an alignment,
you should use \leaders or \hrulefill (see The TeXbook).

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.36 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.36 }

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.36 }

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.36 }

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Too many }'s.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox 
l.37 \end{figure}

You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.37 \end{figure}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.37 \end{figure}

Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
%\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photos/IMG_20180615_144758.jpg}
\caption{pic 1}
\end{subfigure}%
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photos/IMG_20180615_144616.jpg}
\caption{pic 2} 
\end{subfigure}%
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photos/IMG_20180615_145752.jpg}
\caption{pic 3} 
\end{subfigure}%
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photos/IMG_20180615_153117.jpg}
\caption{pic 4}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Photos of the process}
\label{photos}
%}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You only need to put the closing brace *before* `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photos/IMG_20180615_144758.jpg}
\caption{pic 1}
\end{subfigure}%
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photos/IMG_20180615_144616.jpg}
\caption{pic 2} 
\end{subfigure}%
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photos/IMG_20180615_145752.jpg}
\caption{pic 3} 
\end{subfigure}%
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photos/IMG_20180615_153117.jpg}
\caption{pic 4}
\end{subfigure}%
}

\caption{Photos of the process}
\label{photos}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```