# renewcommand as a simple wrapper: pass all arguments and options to the underlying command

Tags: macros, graphics

I "just" want to wrap all `\includegraphics` commands inside a `\centerline`, i.e.:

```
\includegraphics[width=3cm, keepaspectratio]{img}
```

automatically replaced by

```
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=3cm, keepaspectratio]{img}}
```

So I need a macro in the preamble, but I don't know how to pass *all* *arguments*, and *all options* *unchanged* using `renewcommand`:

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\includegraphics[???]{#1}}
```

Do I have to go through the hassle of using `\ifnextchar[` myself? (example here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314/95423); or do I need a package?

I stress out that the number of provided optional arguments is variable, and that even solutions with [xparse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2925/95423) or [etoolbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63041/95423) require knowing the number of options...

---

P.S: why `\centerline`? Because it allows images to be larger than textwidth (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57702/95423)).
P.P.S: Thank you for highlighting potential drawbacks of rigidly centered includegraphics, although I am mostly interested in the general way to implement this redefinition.

Comment: What if you need `\includegraphics` *not* centered? By the way, `\centerline` is a foreign command to LaTeX.

Comment: I don't think I will often need uncentered graphics, as they will all be figures. In that case I would simply define an `\oldincludegraphics` I suppose.

Comment: While you could do it with`\let\svincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\centerline{\svincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}`, the problem is you will be forever precluded from sticking two images on a single line.  Preferable would be to define a new command, like `\clincludegraphics`, specifically for applying `\centerline`.

Comment: images larger than textwidth with no warning would prevent publication in many published sources so be careful where you use this.

Comment: It's for my PhD thesis, so I am quite free. Some friends even used a layout with a huge margin, where all the figures go, and a thin column of text on the side. Now this is a whole new debate, but I personally like having a narrow column of text, except for figures. As this is probably unorthodox, I'd be happy to be redirected to opinions/rules/convention on the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, you can do this:

```
\let\includegraphicsori=\includegraphics
\def\includegraphics#1#{\includegraphicsA{#1}}
\def\includegraphicsA#1#2{\centerline{\includegraphicsori#1{#2}}}
```

The optional parameter (if any) is `#1`, the real parameter is `#2` of the `\includegraphicsA`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I realise I was confused by the denomination "an optional parameter", which  refer to *everything* inside *one* pair of brackets, even when there are several comma separated values... thank you for you time.

Comment: Can you please explain why there is `#1#` in the second line? shouldn't `#` be followed by a numeral?

Comment: This is special exepion of TeX syntax of macros. The parameter text should be terminated by `#`. It menas that the parameter is separated to the first occurence of `{`. In our example in one use `\inclgr {figure}`, then `#1` is empty. Or `\incrgr*[um, pluptf]{figure}` then `#1` is `*[um, pluptf]`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how useful this would be. If you use `\includegraphics` inside a `figure` environment, you just specify `\centering` in the environment.

However, here's an implementation that also allows a `nocenter` option,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \plasma_includegraphics:w \includegraphics
\cs_new_protected:Nn \plasma_includegraphics:nn
 {
  \plasma_includegraphics:w [ #1 ] { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \plasma_includegraphics:nn { V }

\keys_define:nn { plasma/includegraphics }
 {
  center .bool_set:N = \l__plasma_includegraphics_center_bool,
  center .default:n = true,
  nocenter .bool_set_inverse:N = \l__plasma_includegraphics_center_bool,
  nocenter .default:n = true,
  unknown .code:n =
   \clist_put_right:Nx \l__plasma_includegraphics_options_clist
    {
     \l_keys_key_str \tl_if_empty:nF { #1 } { = \exp_not:n { #1 } }
    },
 }

\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{sO{}m}
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l__plasma_includegraphics_options_clist
  \keys_set:nn { plasma/includegraphics } { center, #2 }
  \IfBooleanT{#1}
   {
    \keys_set:nn { plasma/includegraphics } { clip=true }
   }
  \bool_if:NTF \l__plasma_includegraphics_center_bool
   {
    \par\noindent\makebox[\columnwidth]
     {
      \plasma_includegraphics:Vn \l__plasma_includegraphics_options_clist { #3 }
     }
    \par
   }
   {
    \plasma_includegraphics:Vn \l__plasma_includegraphics_options_clist { #3 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=3cm,angle=30]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics*[width=5cm,viewport=0 0 72 72]{example-image-a}

\noindent
X\includegraphics[nocenter,height=2ex]{example-image-b}Y

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a simpler way? Yes, there is, but preserving the full syntax of `\includegraphics` is a bit of a nuisance.

```latex
\usepackage{letltxmacro} % <--- necessary

\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\nocenterincludegraphics\includegraphics

\protected\def\includegraphics{%
  \@ifstar{\plasma@includegraphics@clip}{\plasma@includegraphics}%
}
\newcommand\plasma@includegraphics[2][]{%
  \par\noindent
  \makebox[\columnwidth]{\nocenterincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \par
}
\newcommand\plasma@includegraphics@clip[2][]{%
  \plasma@includegraphics[clip,#1]{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

You can use `\nocenterincludegraphics` for including something without centering.

**Note.** `\LetLtxMacro` isn't really necessary *with the current* definition of `\includegraphics`. But things change and using a simple `\let` might reveal disastrous if the implementation changes.

Comment: Certainly robust and flexible, however for a basic user like me this looks intimidating. I'll use that if I encounter limitations in the simpler approach.

Comment: Maybe my question is asking for a bad workaround, and I should indeed redefine the `figure` environment instead of the `\includegraphics` command. We always find better answers after formulating the question ^^

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Using `\centerline` inside a macro in LaTeX is always a bad idea. It *doesn't* do what you believe it to. Well it *almost* does it, but you might be puzzled by its result in some cases.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong I added a “less intimidating” code. But, really, the idea is wrong to start with.

Comment: Thank you, it's amazing to be helped so quickly. I started getting through macro & tex tutorials, but to be honest I also should write some actual thesis content. Nevertheless your code helped me getting started. I'll ask a new question for redefining the figure environment then ;)