# renewenvironment with opening brace before, and closing brace after (to center wide floats)

Tags: macros, floats

I'm sorry if I lack the basics of tex and macro definitions, I only started to get into it.

My concrete question is how to get [Custom margins for figure in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57702/95423), in particular how to [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/95423). But I want this setting defined **in a macro**.

So this is why I ask a more general question about macro syntax: how to nest the content of my environment inside a command? I thought I just needed to replace `{ ... }` by `\bgroup ... \egroup` but
my attempt at adapting the ["`makebox`" approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57706/95423) in a `\renewenvironment` failed:

```
\let\origfig=\figure
\let\endorigfig=\endfigure

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
\origfig
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]\bgroup\centering
}{
\egroup\endorigfig
}
```

throws

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
```

---

P.S: as for this specific float width question, I'll happily use packages that get the job done, like `floatrow` (but I haven't managed to produce the desired result yet).

P.P.S: I want to redefine the table environment this way as well.

---

**EDIT**. I added a minimal example based on @egreg's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Install package "mwe" to get the example image.
\usepackage{graphicx}

% From: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541576
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@floatboxreset\expandafter{\@floatboxreset\centering}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% To visualise the text margins:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth, height=0.1\textheight]{example-image-a.png}
\end{figure}

2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can not use `\bgroup` to delimit a macro argument `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]\bgroup` can not work (not specific to `\makebox`)

Comment: Ok, so do I have to use a package like `environ` instead?

Comment: possibly yes but redefining the float environments is tricky there is a lot going on that can break, there is almost always a better way

Comment: Apart from that, are you sure you _want_ to add `\makebox` in this way, it means that you will get no warning if your figures/tables overflow the text block or even the page. Getting warnings if the output is not visible is a feature not a problem to be solved.

Comment: I think that you should change your title to include **(centering wide floats)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to do this way, but to hook in the float mechanism itself.

There is currently no user interface for this, so you need some low level code:

```latex
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@floatboxreset\expandafter{\@floatboxreset\centering}
\makeatother
```

This code in the preamble of your document will make LaTeX do `\centering` as the last command before examining a float contents. So every `figure` and `table` environment will have their contents centered.

On the other hand, it's not so difficult to get used to

```latex
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
```

and forget the issue.

Comment: I don't understand, I tried this with `\begin{figure}\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth, height=1cm]{img}\end{figure}`, and the image is still overflowing on the right...

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Of course you don't usually want to insert images larger than the text width. Why would you?

Answer (score 4):

egreg has shown how to add centering but to answer your question about `\bgroup`.

After a definition such as

```
\newcommand\zzz[1]{this (#1)}
```

Then the argument `#1` has to be a single token or a group surrounded by explicit `{` and `}` (or in general characters with catcode 1 and 2).  `\bgroup` is defined by `\let` so is an implicit character which may be used for tex grouping but not for undelimited arguments.

```
\zzz\bgroup zzz\egroup
```

The argument `#1` of `\zzz`  is just the single token `\bgroup` so it would expand to

```
 this (\bgroup)zzz\egroup
```

and typeset as

```
> this ()zzz
```

In that case you get no error, but unwanted output. In general the unexpected `\bgroup` may make arbitrary low level errors with mis-matched groups, depending on the details of the command.

Answer (score 4):

The `memoir` class provides the `centerfloat` command for centering floats wider than the `textwidth`.

Try this modified version of your MWE.

```
% widefloatprob.tex  SE 541571

\documentclass{article}

% Install package "mwe" to get the example image.
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\centerfloat}{%
  \parindent \z@
  \leftskip \z@ \@plus 1fil \@minus \textwidth
  \rightskip\leftskip
  \parfillskip \z@skip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% To visualise the text margins:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

\begin{figure}[h]
\centerfloat
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth, height=0.1\textheight]{example-image-a.png}
\end{figure}

2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 

\end{document}
```

The `\centerfloat` can be used for any float that has a known width, such as a `tabular` (table).

Comment: I take it \hsize=\linewidth=\columnwidth (ignoring the glue), so \caption will fit normally.

Comment: @JohnKormylo The caption fits within the textwidth. It appears as it would with a normal sized float.

Answer (score 0):

As the `\makebox` approach requires the figure as an argument, you could parse the figure name as a parameter of a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{mwe}       %examplary figure "example-image-a"
\usepackage{blindtext} %examplary text "\blindtext"

\begin{document}
  %definitions of the new environment "fig" 
  \newenvironment{fig}[2][\textwidth]
  {\begin{figure}[htbp]\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=#1,height=1cm]{#2}}}
  {\end{figure}}

  %example
  \begin{fig}[1.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:key}
  \end{fig}

  \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Alternatively you could instead define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\includegraphicsCenter}[2][]{\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphicsCenter[width=1.2\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:key2}
\end{figure}
```