# Redefine longtable environment (as used by pandoc)

Tags: floats, longtable

The XY problem --as is often requested on SE forums-- is how to automatically set the following parameters of a longtable environment (because I'm using Pandoc to generate the latex):

- width ratio of the page
- centering
- font size

I achieved that previously on the table environment ([renewenvironment with opening brace before, and closing brace after (to center wide floats)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541571/95423)), also helped by existing macros from the Pandoc default template:

```latex
% Original macro to customize table
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}[1][\fps@table]{
  \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\@float{table}[#1]}
  \@tempa\centerfloat\footnotesize%
}{
  \end@float
}
\makeatother
```

Copy-pasting the above and replacing "table" by "longtable" just does not work:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{longtable}[1][\fps@longtable]{
  \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\@float{longtable}[#1]}
  \@tempa\centerfloat\footnotesize%
}{
  \end@float
}
\makeatother
```

I suppose there is no such macro as `\fps@longtable` in the longtable source, and also that one longtable might indeed be made of multiple floats... So what is the macro that I should redefine?

Comment: longtable doesn't float so there is nothing corresponding to \fps@longtable and certainly you do not want \end@float at the end.   longtables are centred by default, so don't you just want to add `\footnotesize` before the table?

Comment: It is not clear what changes you want, but perhaps `\let\oldlongtable\longtable \def\longtable{\footnotesizse\oldlongtable}`

Comment: yes, I just want a `\centerfloat\footnotesize` before the longtable content

Comment: what do you want \centerfloat to do given that longtables are centred and do not float?

Comment: Right, it's in order to set a larger width than current textwidth (by a factor of 1.2). I get the footnotesize with your code, however, regarding the width, it is constrained to `\textwidth`.

Comment: why not simply specify a larger `\textwidth` ? but anyway you can set `\LTleft` and `\LTright` to `-.1\textwith plus 1fill` and it'll allow to spill 10% at either side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand the question you can do

```
\let\oldlongtable\longtable
\longtable{%
\LTleft-.1\textwidth plus 1fill
\LTright\LTleft
\footnotesize
\oldlongtable}
```

To get footnotesize tables that may spill into the margin by 10% of textwidth.

Comment: For the end of the story, I used your solution, and included a `\setlength{\columnwidth}{1.2\columnwidth}` to make it as wide as wanted (and the `\def` before `\longtable`).