# image negative left marign

Tags: graphics, floats, margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth)

I'm using a fairly small width for my papers but this way my images get smaller. 
Is there a way to place images more to the left so they can be bigger.
Because now i only get bigger images to the right.

Currently I use:

```
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{image.jpg} 
\caption{caption}
\label{label} 
\end{figure}
```

[image: example]

Comment: You need to "pull" it.'\hspace*{-30pt}\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{image.jpg}'

Comment: @YiannisLazarides LaTeX can center it without any need to guess.

Comment: @egreg Sure, but the OP wanted to "to place images more to the left so they can be bigger..."

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I assumed that the OP wanted to center the image with respect to the text column.