# consistently centering figures and tables that exceed margins

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth)

I have a myriad of plots to include in my document and for best quality they all fall beyond the document template margins. Following another thread/question I found I could use the following `\advance\leftskip-3.1cm` to center my images going over the margins:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \caption{Roofline Minimum Cut with inc. evaluation}
        \begin{center}
    \advance\leftskip-3.1cm
        \includegraphics[scale=1.3]{pdf/roofline_mincut_inc.pdf}
        \end{center}
     \label{fig:roofline_mincut_inc}
 \end{figure}
```

The problem is that all images of the exact same size need tweaking the leftskip distance so they all get centered, this is too hacky and unmaintainable, is there a way to simply say "forget about margins and put this image centered as is"?

UPDATE: Oh great, thank you for closing it! :( all solutions proposed in the linked Answer produce the same ugly flushed result and each figure needs special tweaking to get it properly centered.

Comment: The solutions in the linked answer work fine for me. Could you edit your question to show a complete minimal example document using one of the solutions from the linked question that shows the behaviour you describe?

Comment: Closing a question is not final, it can easily be reopened once the question is changed to provide the necessary information. As it is now, closing it as a duplicate is the only thing that seemed reasonable, because the information provided suggests that the approaches in the linked question would help you. If you provide an example where the approaches don't work, we'll hopefully be able to help sort it out.