# Let caption float into margin

Tags: floats, captions, margins

I searched for a long time to find a solution to let a caption of a figure and/or a table expand into the outside margin. I'm able to get a figure/table where the width is `textwidth` plus `marginparwidth`. See my MWE down below using a solution [on stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin).

**EDIT:** Thanks to Steven B. Segletes, who found the right question, I was able to fix this with the command `\captionsetup{margin={0pt,-\marginparwidth}}` using the `caption`-package. I edited the code below, too.

```
\documentclass[%
    12pt,
    BCOR=15mm,
    captions=tableheading,
    DIV=current,
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[
    top=30mm,
    bottom=40mm,
    inner=30mm,
    outer=55mm,
    marginparsep=5mm,
    marginparwidth=30mm,
    ]{geometry}

\usepackage[leqno, fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, tabularx}

\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\newlength\fullwidth\fullwidth=\textwidth \advance\fullwidth by \marginparwidth

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \checkoddpage
    \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}
    \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{% 
        \includegraphics[width=\fullwidth]{figure}
    }%
    \captionsetup{margin={0pt,-\marginparwidth}}
    \caption{Long captiontext do get two lines, so I can see, if the caption expands into the margin.\label{fig:label}}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
    \captionsetup{margin={0pt,-\marginparwidth}}
    \caption{Instabile Isotope können unter Aussendung von Kernteilchen zerfallen. Dabei bilden sie neue Isotope.\label{tab:radiozerfall}}
    \checkoddpage
    \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}
    \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{% 
        \begin{tabularx}{1.01\fullwidth}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}XXXXXX<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}
        \toprule
        Produkt       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Strahlungs-} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Eigenschaften der Strahlungsteilchen}  \\
                       & teilchen           & bezeichnung          & Kernladungs\-zahl & Nukleonen\-zahl & Durchdrin\-gung \\
        $^{A-4}_{Z-2}\text{E}$ & He-Kern            & $\alpha$-Strahlung   & $+2$              & 4               & gering          \\
        $^{A}_{Z+1}\text{E}$   & Elektron           & $\beta$-Strahlung    & $-1$              & 0               & mittel          \\
        unverändert            & Photon             & $\gamma$-Strahlung   & $\phantom{-}0$    & 0               & groß            \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which margin? Outside margin?

Comment: This might be related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98971/over-wide-figure-with-caption-of-the-same-width-that-both-spill-out-of-the-right

Comment: Yes, the outside margin.

Comment: Thanks to Steven, he found the right question. I was blind, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an options using the `caption` package and its `margin` key (I added the `showframe` option to `geometry` so as to have a visual help for the page layout; I also added `\marginparsep` to the width of the figure, table and captions, but this is optional):

```
\documentclass[%
    12pt,
    BCOR=15mm,
    captions=tableheading,
    DIV=current,
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[
showframe,
    top=30mm,
    bottom=40mm,
    inner=30mm,
    outer=55mm,
    marginparsep=5mm,
    marginparwidth=30mm,
    ]{geometry}

\usepackage[leqno, fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, tabularx}

\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\newlength\fullwidth\fullwidth=\textwidth \advance\fullwidth by \marginparwidth
\advance\fullwidth by \marginparsep
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength\extraWd
\setlength\extraWd{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup{margin={0cm,-\extraWd}}
    \checkoddpage
    \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}
    \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{% 
        \includegraphics[width=\fullwidth]{figure}
    }%
    \caption{Long captiontext do get two lines, so I can see, if the caption expands into the margin.\label{fig:label}}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
    \captionsetup{margin={0cm,-\extraWd}}
    \caption{Instabile Isotope können unter Aussendung von Kernteilchen zerfallen. Dabei bilden sie neue Isotope.\label{tab:radiozerfall}}
    \checkoddpage
    \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}
    \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{% 
        \begin{tabularx}{1.01\fullwidth}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}XXXXXX<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}
        \toprule
        Produkt       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Strahlungs-} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Eigenschaften der Strahlungsteilchen}  \\
                       & teilchen           & bezeichnung          & Kernladungs\-zahl & Nukleonen\-zahl & Durchdrin\-gung \\
        $^{A-4}_{Z-2}\text{E}$ & He-Kern            & $\alpha$-Strahlung   & $+2$              & 4               & gering          \\
        $^{A}_{Z+1}\text{E}$   & Elektron           & $\beta$-Strahlung    & $-1$              & 0               & mittel          \\
        unverändert            & Photon             & $\gamma$-Strahlung   & $\phantom{-}0$    & 0               & groß            \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]