# Compatibility issue with \renewenvironment{figure} and [H] placement

Tags: floats, environments, incompatibility

This is related to [Shift all floats on page horizontally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302631). While trying to redefine the standard `figure` environment I've run into compatibility issues with the `[H]` placement specifier from the float package.

Consider the simple example below which just adds some text to be displayed at the beginning and the end of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][\fps@figure]
  {\@float{figure}[#1]before}
  {after\end@float}
\makeatother

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
   \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This works as expected with the standard latex figure placement specifiers by displaying the graphics between the "before" and "after" words, as illustrated by the image below. However, when I try to use `[H]` instead of `[h]` the text supposed to appear after the graphics is gone. Any suggestions how the example above could be fixed to work with the `[H]` placement specifier?

[image]

Comment: Don't use the `[H]` specifier under any circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lives in the code of the `float` package: If the placement `[H]` is used, `\endfigure` will be redefined locally with no respect on the original definition of `\endfigure`:

```
\def\@float@HH#1[H]{%
% Locally redefine the end of the environment.
  \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\float@endH
  ...
```

As consequence the following code compiles fine, although `\jhzsweiurziuewzriuewzritewt` is (obviously) not defined at all and therefore should give an error when used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][\fps@figure]
  {\@float{figure}[#1]before}
  {\jhzsweiurziuewzriuewzritewt} % not defined but compiles fine anyway ;-)
\makeatother

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
   \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What can we do about it? Patching `\float@endH` as well. We do this inside the redefinition of `figure` (and not globally) so the patch does not affect the other floating environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][\fps@figure]
  {% Next two code lines: Adaption to "HERE" feature of the float package
   \let\float@endH@ORI\float@endH
   \def\float@endH{after\float@endH@ORI}%
   % ...or \pretocmd{\float@endH}{after}{}{} when using `etoolbox`
   \@float{figure}[#1]before}
  {after\end@float}
\makeatother

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
   \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks for your answer and the thorough explanation of the problem. Using your suggestion I was also able to solve my original issue described in [Shift all floats on page horizontally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302631).

Comment: @aoles I just realized that patching `\float@endH` globally was a bad idea of mine (since this would affect all floating environments), so I moved the patch inside the redefinition of `figure`.

Comment: Obviously undefined? `\jhzsweiurziuewzriuewzritewt` is my favorite name for marking up spectral sequences; it has thirteen mandatory arguments and fourteen optional ones, just to keep the syntax at the bare minimum. ;-)

Comment: Thank you @AxelSommerfeldt for the update! In this specific example it makes of course much more sense to redefine it only for the `figure` environment, but for my other question [Shift all floats on page horizontally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302631/102422) the global patch is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\fps@figure` doesn't have an H option.  To implement the H option from the figure package, you would need something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newenvironment{Hfigure}{\setcaptiontype{figure}%
  \vskip\textfloatsep\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}}%
  {\end{minipage}\vskip\textfloatsep\noindent}

\begin{document}
before
\begin{Hfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{test}
\end{Hfigure}
after
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Unfortunately, your solution won't work for the specific case I described, because I would like to:  **1.**  redefine the standard figure environment, and **2.** support the placement specifier [H] defined in the float package, i.e. be able to write \begin{figure}[H].