# Figure + table wider than textwidth

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment

I have a figure and a table placed next to one another, but they are wider than the textwidth. Now I want to center them so they exceed the textwidth margins. Can this be done?

Edit: currently I have something like this, but I can't seem to get this wider than the textwidth.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
 \includegraphics[height=5cm]{figure}
}{%
  \caption{figure caption}%
  \label{figure}
}
\capbtabbox{%
\begin{tabular}{ |c|}
  HERE COMES THE TABLE
\end{tabular}
}{%
  \caption{table}%
}
\end{floatrow}
%\vspace{-1cm}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please post a Mininal Working Example (MWE)!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth)

Comment: @ThorstenDonig But how to do this with a table and a figure (instead of 2 figs)?

Comment: My comment was based on the first version of your question which did not contain any code. A *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) could help to solve the problem. A code snippet is not very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\DeclareMarginSet`, you can declare a margin set allowing you to hang the object on both margins (there are predefined settings `hangleft`, `hangright` for each margin individually, but not for both of them simultaneouly); then, you can invoke this margin set together with an appropriate value for `floatwidth` and `rowfill=yes`. Something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\DeclareMarginSet{hangboth}{\setfloatmargins*{\hskip-4cm}{\hskip-4cm}}

\begin{document}

\thisfloatsetup{floatwidth=\paperwidth,rowfill=yes,margins=hangboth}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[!ht]\CenterFloatBoxes
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}}
  {\caption{figure caption}\label{figure}}
\ttabbox[\FBwidth]
  {\begin{tabular}{lll}
  column1a & column2a & column3a \\
  column1b & column2b & column3b \\
  column1c & column2c  & column3c \\
  column1d & column2d & column3d
  \end{tabular}}
  {\caption{table}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `[!ht]` was only used for the example; I am bot recommending its use.

To have the caption for the table below it (although it's usual for table captions to appear above the table), you can use `\floatbox` instead of `\ttabbox` for the table and perhaps do some additional adjustment for the vertical alignment using `heightadjust` and `valign`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[rawfloats]{floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareMarginSet{hangboth}{\setfloatmargins*{\hskip-4cm}{\hskip-4cm}}

\begin{document}

\thisfloatsetup{floatwidth=\paperwidth,rowfill=yes,margins=hangboth,heightadjust=all,valign=b}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}}
  {\caption{figure caption}\label{figure}}
\floatbox{table}[\FBwidth]
  {\caption{table}}
  {\begin{tabular}{lll}
  column1a & column2a & column3a \\
  column1b & column2b & column3b \\
  column1c & column2c & column3c \\
  column1d & column2d & column3d
  \end{tabular}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Any idea on how to put the caption under the table?

Comment: @MaVe: Tables have their captions above.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig And can you force the caption to be under the table?

Comment: @MaVe please see my updated answer.