# center image when's bigger than textwidth

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, color

I have an image that is larger than the line width and I want to center it and I also want to have a colored frame around. I can get this two things done one at the time, but don't know how to achieve both!

for the colored square I use this:

```
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{{\color{#1}\fbox{\normalcolor#2}}} %in the preamble

\mybox{grigio}{\includegraphics[scale=0.43]{life.jpg}} %in the document
```

I manage to center the image with this code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[\columnwidth]{\includegraphics[...]{...}}
\end{figure}
```

Note that I don't want the image's width to be = to the text width. I want it bigger, but still centered.
Thanks ;)

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth (or one of the linked questions) help.

Comment: To close-voters: this is not exactly a duplicate. The OP is aware of the solutions given in other posts to center an image wider than `\linewidth`; the question here is how to combine this with adding a colored frame.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I don't know why the combination doesn't work: `\makebox[..]{\mybox{..}{...}}`, which is a duplicate of the linked post apart from a different macro that is used, in my opinion. Moreover, both your and SBS's answers follow exactly the same approach of nesting "whatever you want done" inside a `\makebox`, which is what is suggested as solution in the linked post.

Comment: @Werner I don't see any explicit mention to nesting something inside a \makebox in the linked post of the first comment.  That's why I considered this not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `\colorbox` (requires `xcolor`) inside the `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{8pt}%<- optional for padding
  \colorbox{cyan}{%
    \includegraphics[width=16cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `stackengine` package can do it by stacking the image atop a null argument, with the `\useanchorwidth` parameter set `T`.  In that way, the perceived width of the stack is the width of the anchor, which, in this case, is the width of a null argument, or 0pt.

For the frame (I opted for a double frame), I just put it in a double `\fbox`, after setting `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` to desired values and using nested `\color` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=4pt
\centering
\stackon[0pt]{}{%
  \color{blue}\fbox{%
    \color{magenta}\fbox{%
      \includegraphics[width=16cm,height=3cm]{example-image}%
    }%
  }%
}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]