# Create a centered image with \textwidth in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, textwidth

I want to place a tikzpicture in landscape mode in the center of an A4 page. However, I can't use the `\textwidth` and `\textheight` commands because this will result in `overfull \hbox...` or `overfull \vbox...` errors and an empty first page. I assume there is some tiny  margin or indentation somewhere somehow?

I've looked at a [couple](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64046/why-isnt-textwidth-the-width-of-the-text) of [threads](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128406/center-image-whens-bigger-than-textwidth) here, but nothing worked so far. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{minimal}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (0.999\textwidth,0.999\textheight);

  % this will give "overfull \hbox..." or "overfull \vbox..." errors
  % and create an empty first page
  % \draw (0, 0) rectangle (\textwidth,\textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! You need to take into account the line width. (I switched to article, as suggested by fractal.) On each end, the bounding box will be increased by `\pgflinewidth/2`, so you need to correct for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%\begin{center} %<- not needed
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (\textwidth-\pgflinewidth,\textheight-\pgflinewidth);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaah. Of course. Nice, thanks!