# Horizontally align subfloat in figure

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I am putting three figures on one row, and the width is not enough if I want to show them clearly (big enough). I used to use `hspace` to manually shift the figure, but it doesn't work this time. (It only affects the first row.) How could I shift the whole figure? I need to left shift the whole figure for certain distance for this page, I think.

This is one MWE do illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\IDCTFigureHeight}{2.8}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \vspace{-10pt}
  \subfloat[v1 with buffer size 16]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\IDCTFigureHeight in]{images/local/v1_16.png}}
  \subfloat[v1 with buffer size 100]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\IDCTFigureHeight in]{images/local/v1_100.png}}
  \subfloat[v1 with buffer size 200]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\IDCTFigureHeight in]{images/local/v1_200.png}}
  \vspace{-10pt}
  \\
  \subfloat[v2 with buffer size 16]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\IDCTFigureHeight in]{images/local/v2_16.png}}
  \subfloat[v2 with buffer size 100]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\IDCTFigureHeight in]{images/local/v2_100.png}}
  \subfloat[v2 with buffer size 200]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\IDCTFigureHeight in]{images/local/v2_200.png}}
  \vspace{-10pt}
  \\
  \subfloat[v3 with buffer size 16]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\IDCTFigureHeight in]{images/local/v3_16.png}}
  \subfloat[v3 with buffer size 100]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\IDCTFigureHeight in]{images/local/v3_100.png}}
  \subfloat[v3 with buffer size 200]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=\IDCTFigureHeight in]{images/local/v3_200.png}}
  \caption{destination-fifo with different buffer size.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use a `\makebox` as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth, only use one for each line of subfloats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add also `\hspace` to the second and third rows if you use a blank line or `\par` instead of `\\`. That is, change:

```
\vspace{-10pt}
\\
```

by

```
\vspace{-10pt}


\hspace{-2cm}
```

or

```
\vspace{-10pt}\par    
\hspace{-2cm}
```