# LaTex Image Problems (Align and position)

Tags: graphics

I've a problem with image import in LaTex.
I want to set all images centered, i tried a lot of commands found around here but
nothing seems works. Now I have encountered another problem, because images aren't positioned in the right part of the document @_@
I'm new with LaTex, so probably is a noob's mistake.

Here is the code:

```
\section{Cliente}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \includegraphics[page=1,width=1.5\textwidth,center]{./Query-OrderByRandOttimizzata.png}
\end{figure}

\section{Contratto}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \includegraphics[page=1,width=1.5\textwidth,center]{./10Contratti.png}
\end{figure}

\section{Societ\`a}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \includegraphics[page=1,width=1\textwidth,center]{./10Societa.png}
\end{figure}

\section{Impianti}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \includegraphics[page=1,width=1\textwidth,center]{./10Impianti.png}
    \caption{Nota: in questo caso si \`e costretti a utilizzare la query con ORDER BY per via della condizione sull' ID non rispettata.}
\end{figure}
```

I can't post the image for results, but it's like this:

```
8.1 Cliente
Image. -> Not centered.

8.2 Contratto
Image. -> Not centered.

8.3 Società
NO IMAGE -> It is in the next page.

8.4 Impianti
NO IMAGE -> It is in the next page.
```

Another question:
How can I insert the result of a query SQL in LaTex without use a screenshot?
With "result of a query" I mean:

```
+----------+----------+
| Col1     | Col2     |
+----------+----------+
| Val1     | Val2     |
+----------+----------+
```

Hope that someone can help me,
Thanks :)

P.s.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Insert `\centering` inside the `figure` environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: 1) PNG does not support multiple images (animation) unlike GIF. Thus `page=1` is not needed. 2) `width=1.5\textwidth` means the image will *never* fit in `\textwidth` and not fit in `\linewidth` that is usually equal or smaller than `\textwidth`. The result is an overfull `\hbox` warning and centering is not an issue. Smaller images can be horizontally centered by using `\centering` at the start of the `figure` environment. 3) `center` is *not* an option for `\includegraphics`.

Comment: For the centering issue, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth, though with `.5\textwidth` it may run off the page on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\centering` or `\begin{center}`, maybe this [page](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/uncategorized/center-centering/) help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With \begin{center} the images are in their right position but why aren't centered? My images have big width, and if I increase the scale value the left and right margins do not remain the same.

Comment: Try using \begin{figure}[H!], Here you have a more detailed explanation, [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)