# is possible to use a part of the margins with figure?, as with tabular

Tags: floats, margins, subfloats

is posible to use a part of the margins with FIGURE?, as in this example with tabular

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{incgraph}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}

jdhjfdks fjkf hjdshjds hfj kdhjk h dj fhdj  k  fhhfjdfd dsj fl k d sjf kd j fljkasdfk j sd alk  flka s j f kla sjf lkd sj fk l sajf kl dsj fl k d sjf kd j fljkasdfk j sd alk  flka s j f kla sjf lkd sj fk l sajf kl dsj fl k d sjf kd j fl\\
%\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{TS-Applicationss.eps}
After a table we have.. THIS\\
%\setstretch{1}
\noindent

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
      \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a.eps} &
      \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a.eps} &
      \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a.eps}   \\
      {\small Way 1}& {\small Way 2} & {\small Way 3}\\
      \hline
      \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a.eps} & \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a.eps} &\\
      {\small Forma 4}& {\small Forma 5} &\\
      \hline
\end{tabular}\\


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Forma 1\label{example-image-a.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a.eps}}
\subcaptionbox{Forma 2\label{example-image-a.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{d32-s100-i32-t8-opvec2.eps}}
\subcaptionbox{Forma 3\label{example-image-b.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{d32-s100-i32-t8-opvec3.eps}}
%
\subcaptionbox{Forma 4\label{example-image-a.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{d32-s100-i32-t8-opvec4.eps}}
\subcaptionbox{Forma 5\label{example-image-a.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{d32-s100-i2-t1-opvec5.eps}}
%\subcaptionbox{$r_i=0.01, \forall i, m=9$\label{ES-P-todo-0_01-m9.eps}}
%{\includegraphics[width=.31\linewidth]{ES-P-todo-0_01-m9.eps}}
\caption{Evolución de múltiples simulaciones con diferenes formas de generar $N(x_k)$.}\label{BT-A-1-evosegunformadevecindario}
\end{figure}
AFTER The big BIG


\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. You're using a `\linewidth` scaling in the latter part, while there's a fixed width scaling used in the former part. If you want a figure's contents to straddle the text margins, then might be interested in [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/5764). The suggestion is to place the contents in a `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}` (which will automatically center it horizontally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption,mwe}

\newlength\fullwidth
\setlength\fullwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}
\begin{document}  
After a table we have.. THIS\\

\noindent
\makebox[\fullwidth][c]{%
  \parbox{0.3\fullwidth}{\centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\Way 1}\hfill
  \parbox{0.3\fullwidth}{\centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\Way 2}\hfill
  \parbox{0.3\fullwidth}{\centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\Way 3}%
}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\makebox[\fullwidth][l]{%
  \subcaptionbox{Forma 1\label{example-image-a}}
    {\includegraphics[width=.24\fullwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subcaptionbox{Forma 2\label{example-image-a}}
   {\includegraphics[width=.24\fullwidth]{d32-s100-i32-t8-opvec2}}
  \subcaptionbox{Forma 3\label{example-image-b}}
   {\includegraphics[width=.24\fullwidth]{d32-s100-i32-t8-opvec3}}
  \subcaptionbox{Forma 4\label{example-image-a}}
    {\includegraphics[width=.24\fullwidth]{d32-s100-i32-t8-opvec4}}%
}
\caption{Evolución de múltiples simulaciones con diferenes formas de generar $N(x_k)$.}\label{BT-A-1-evosegunformadevecindario}
\end{figure}
AFTER The big BIG

\end{document}
```

[image]