# Make images ignore left margin

Tags: graphics

I would like to fit 2 plots next to each other on a page. These 2 plots need to be large enough, to the numbers on them can be read.

Currently, I use the following to add the images:

```
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{./plots/fig1.png}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{./plots/fig2.png}
```

But this leads to the following layout:

[image: example]

How can I change this so that the left margin is ignored and these 2 images are centered? Or any other suggestion on how I can create a nice looking layout, since I'm quite new to Latex.

EDIT:

To download [plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2EVy.png) and [plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPmfB.png). This is there original size.

Comment: Did you try to put negative space `\vspace*{-1in}`? Also, you might want to `trim` the white space from the images.

Comment: I mean `\hspace{-1in}`.

Comment: Have you tried `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{...} `? I can't try because I don't have your plots.

Comment: A combination of both comments helped me out. I was just wondering, is there no standard way of doing this? Fiddling with the width en hspace seems not THE way to go.

Comment: If you supply the pictures in your question we can try to see. Maybe if you have the code for each plot is even better, but not critical (I think). That way we can play with the scaling. :D

Comment: If you want the code that generates these plots, I would have to send along some gigabytes of database data too. I'm guessing you don't want that.. I'll just provide the images.

Comment: @JNevens Ah ok. :D

Comment: @JNevens What are the margins for your document?

Comment: @Alenanno I don't think I explicitly specify margins anywhere. I just use `\documentclass{article}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/5764)