# Table width wider than textwidth in threeparttable environment

Tags: threeparttable

I have a table that is wider than `\textwidth`. The table also has footnotes, see the following picture:

[image: example_pic]

I put the table in a `threeparttable` environment, and try to use `\makebox` command mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth) to center the table horizontally. However, it does not work. Moreover, there is no space between the superscript a and (`K$`) in the second row. How can I solve this problem?

The following is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period, skip=5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Optimal results of Example 2}
\label{tab: results2}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccc}
\toprule
Item & ref. 1 & ref. 2 & ref. 3 & ref. 4 & ref. 5 & ref. 6 & ref. 7 & ref. 8 & Our method\\
\midrule
Utility (kW) & 2000 & 3800 & 4200  & & & & & & \\
Capital cost\tnote{a} (k\$) & 163.27 & & & & & & & & \\
Total annual cost (k\$) & 2268.59 & & & & - & & & & \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}   
\begin{tablenotes}                  
\vspace*{-2pt}
\item[a]  {\footnotesize Based on the cost parameters from ref. 6.} 
\vspace*{-2pt}
\item[-]  {\footnotesize Not reported in literature.}   
\end{tablenotes}                
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When reducing the font size to make a wide table "fit" inside the width of the text block, LaTeX doesn't shrink the amount of intercolumn whitspace proportionally. To salvage any chances of having a readable table, it's important to shrink the amount of intercolumn whitespace as well.

I suggest you (i) reorganize the table's header to collect the repeated "Ref." and (ii) use a `tabular*` environment instead of the basic `tabular` environment. With these two changes made, it's still necessary to use `\scriptsize`, for a 30% linear reduction of the main font size.

The first horizontal line in the screenshot is there to illustrate the width of the textblock.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period, skip=5pt}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\hrule  % just to illustrate width of textblock

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX determine whitespace between columns
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Optimal results of Example 2}
\label{tab:results2}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{9}{c}}
\toprule
Item & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Ref.} & Our method\\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\midrule
Utility (kW) & 2000 & 3800.00 & 4200.00  & 4200.00 & 4200.00 & 4200.00& 4200.00 & 4200.00 & 5000.00\\
Capital cost\tnote{a} (k\$) & 163.27 & & & & & & & & \\
Total annual cost (k\$) & 2268.59 & & & & -- & & & & \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular*}  

\begin{tablenotes} 
\scriptsize               
\item[a]  Based on the cost parameters from ref.~6. 
\item[--]  Not reported in literature.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

If you're willing to allow line breaks in the first column, it's possible to use `\footnotesize` (for a 20% reduction in font size) instead of `\scriptsize`. If you choose this method, you could use a `tabularx` environment (instead of the `tabular*` environment used above) to simplify getting optimal line breaks in column 1. I would also suggest you contemplate aligning the numeric data in columns 2 thru 10 on their respective decimal markers, in order to improved the table's readability. I would also replace the slightly comical-looking `k\$` with `10^\textsuperscript{3} \$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period, skip=5pt}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\hrule  % just to illustrate width of textblock

\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} % let LaTeX determine whitespace between columns
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Optimal results of Example 2}
\label{tab:results2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Y*{9}{d{4.2}}@{}}
\toprule
Item & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Ref.} & \mc{Our method}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-9}
& \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} & \mc{5} & \mc{6} & \mc{7} & \mc{8}\\
\midrule
Utility (kW) & 2000 & 3800.00 & 4200.00  & 4200.00 & 4200.00 & 4200.00& 4200.00 & 4200.00 & 5000.00\\
Capital cost\tnote{a} (10\textsuperscript{3}\,\$) 
& 163.27 & & & & & & & & \\
Total annual cost (10\textsuperscript{3}\,\$) 
& 2268.59 & & & & \mc{--} & & & & \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}  

\begin{tablenotes}              
\item[a]   Based on the cost parameters from ref.~6. 
\item[--]  Not reported in literature.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems `\tnote` relies on an internal `\TPToverlap` macro that makes it swallow the leading space. Redefining it not to use it works.

```
\renewcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}
```

(I'm keeping the original behavior for styling the note marks with `TPTtagStyle` from the package definition.)

Centering doesn't work because the table doesn't fit the textarea. You can adjust it with the [`adjustbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/adjustbox) package mentioned in the answer you linked:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    ...                
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period, skip=5pt}

\pagestyle{empty}

% Add space after \tnote
\renewcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}

% Use adjustbox to adjust the threeparttable env to textwidth
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
  \begin{threeparttable}

  \caption{Optimal results of Example 2}
  \label{tab: results2}
  \begin{tabular}{lccccccccc}
  \toprule
  Item & ref. 1 & ref. 2 & ref. 3 & ref. 4 & ref. 5 & ref. 6 & ref. 7 & ref. 8 & Our method\\
  \midrule
  Utility (kW) & 2000 & 3800 & 4200  & & & & & & \\
  Capital cost\tnote{a} (k\$) & 163.27 & & & & & & & & \\
  Total annual cost (k\$) & 2268.59 & & & & - & & & & \\
  \bottomrule 
  \end{tabular}   
  \begin{tablenotes}                  
  \vspace*{-2pt}
  \item[a]  {\footnotesize Based on the cost parameters from ref. 6.} 
  \vspace*{-2pt}
  \item[-]  {\footnotesize Not reported in literature.}   
  \end{tablenotes}                
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image: adjusted large threeparttable]

Comment: It works. But why does the fonts in the table become smaller? I did not see any command that changes the font size in the table. Thanks.

Comment: To henrique: I do not want to change the the table size, but want to center the table horizontally.

Comment: Just insert command: \begin{adjustbox}{center, max width=\1.5textwidth}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    ...                
  \end{threeparttable} and the problem is solved.
\end{adjustbox}

Comment: @Nick, sorry for taking so long to answer. I used `adjustbox` because the table was too wide to fit a page, that's why the fonts got smaller --- and i took that from the answer you linked. Anyway, Mico's answer is much more complete.