# How to create a -left and -right aligned table of a certain width?

Tags: tables, width

I am trying to create a table that spans the width of the page, with two columns, aligned right-ragged and left-ragged respectively. However, this is proving weirdly difficult, as I cannot seem to get my tables to behave the way I want them too width-wise.

An example of what I've tried:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\pagewidth}{l r}
\gray \textbf{Endpoint} & \textbf{0}\\
\end{tabular*}
```

It seems like a simple problem but the inconsistency of table behavior in LaTeX is really getting to me. Help would be appreciated; perhaps I need to use a `minipage`?

Edit:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final, 10pt]{scrartcl} % Paper options using the scrartcl class
\usepackage{scrpage2} % Provides headers and footers configuration
\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows creating custom \section's
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbols
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl} % Advanced table configurations
\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{5cm}
\newcommand{\gray}{\rowcolor[gray]{.90}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} % Center everything in the document

\begin{tabular*}{\pagewidth}{l r}
\gray \textbf{Apple} & \textbf{Banana}\\
\gray Apple & \textbf{Banana}\\
\gray Apple & \textbf{Banana}\\
\end{tabular*}
\begin{itemize} \itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt
\item Apple
\item Apple
\item Mango
\end{itemize}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a working document, not just fragments of code. `\pagewidth` seems weird and is no usually defined length, in addition there are margins to be considered as well! -- What is `\gray` supposed to do?

Comment: This snippet is not long enough? Unfortunately the full document includes a lot of personally identifiable information (it's a resume) that would take me a long time to edit out, so I am very hesitant to paste it here.

Comment: You want to have some help from us but you require to make document around that snippet, i.e. typing work to do. Why should we do that for you?

Comment: @ResMar: We don't want any personal information. See how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)...

Comment: Ok, I made one.

Comment: Off-topic: The usage of `titlesec` together with a KOMA class like `scrartcl` isn't recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[ht]
  \makebox[\textwidth]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/5764
    \begin{tabularx}
        {\pdfpagewidth}
        {>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
      \lipsum*[2] &
      \lipsum*[2]
    \end{tabularx}%
  }
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

With some help from [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`][Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/5764)) you can center content within the text block.

Answer (score 1):

The `tabularx` package will do it.

```
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
    {>{\raggedright}X >{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}X}
\gray \textbf{Apple} & \textbf{Banana}\\
\gray Apple & \textbf{Banana}\\
\gray Apple & \textbf{Banana}\\
\end{tabularx}
```

gives you the first column left-aligned and the second one right-aligned, spanning the page:

[image: grey lines indicate margins]

Edit: changed examples to suit your code.

Comment: One would need `\noindent` as well. Also, only the second `\arraybackslash` is necessary.

Comment: What is `\noindent` for? I added it in several places and it didn't appear to make a difference.
Edited to remove the first `\arraybackslash`.

Comment: Without it, the `tabularx` alone will be indented with `\parindent`, causing an overfull `\hbox` since it's width is `\linewidth`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I did not see an overfull `\hbox` warning when I ran it.