# Caption below figure when using \put and \picture

Tags: floats, captions

I've been attempting to place the caption below using {put} and {picture} (using put is required as the pdf is larger than the textbox). However, I have not been able to make the caption appear below the figure. Hope one of you can help me solve this issue?

Best regards,
Henrik

Current code:

```
\clearpage
\afterpage{ 
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-80,-715){\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{gfx/environment.pdf}}
\end{picture}
\caption{Caption goes here}
\label{fig:environment}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
}
\pagebreak
```

Comment: The PDF is larger than the text box? What about [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/5764)?

Comment: scale the picture with `width=...` and `height=...` and /or `scale=..` and/or ...I  cannot believe that you need the `\put` command.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're aiming at with that code. What's the meaning of `\clearpage\afterpage{...}\pagebreak`? Are you trying to get a blank page, perhaps? And why embedding `\includegraphics` in a `picture` environment?