# Centering Figure without re-scale

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I would like to center a figure made on Tikz. This figure has a specific size which is wider than `\textwidth`,  and it needs to be centered. All options I see use `\resibox` or `\makebox` to center the figures. But I don't want to change the figure size. Are there any option or command to allow this?

Thanks very much in advance. Kind regards,

German

=== SOLUTION ==
As Mr **@David Carlisle** commented below, the solution is uncomment the `\makebox` and set the scaling to `0pt` as follow:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering  
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{1.2\linewidth}
\begingroup
    \fontsize{8}{\baselinestretch}\selectfont
    \makebox[0pt][c]{
    \input{VoltFRFFreq.tikz}
    %}
\endgroup
\caption{A plot of a sphere}
\label{fig.freq}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks again to all people!!

-- EDIT's ---
P.D.-I forgot to mention I use XeLaTeX, I hope it helps. Kind regards,
P.D.D- The code is

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering  
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{1.2\linewidth}
\begingroup
        \fontsize{8}{\baselinestretch}\selectfont
        %\makebox[\figurewidth][c]{
    \input{VoltFRFFreq.tikz}
    %}
\endgroup
\caption{A plot of a sphere}
\label{fig.freq}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's right! Thanks very much!!

Comment: for future reference, shouldn't the question be restated as "Centering box wider than \textwidth" or so ?

Comment: @ChristophFrings -- excellent suggestion, but there's already a question with that heading: [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/579) so this one should probably be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uncomment your `\makebox`

```
  %\makebox[\figurewidth][c]{
```

but change the specified width to `0pt` instead of `\figurewidth`

Comment: Solved! Brilliant!!!!

Answer (score 0):

since your figure is wider than the text width, you want to make it look to latex like it is narrower.  here's one possibility (just the group with the figure):

```
\noindent\hss
\begingroup
        \fontsize{8}{\baselinestretch}\selectfont
    \input{VoltFRFFreq.tikz}
\endgroup
\hss\par
```

Comment: Hi Barbara 

The code you propose gives me an error:
    ! Infinite glue shrinkage found in a paragraph.
I forgot to mention I use XeLaTeX, I hope it helps. 

Kind regards,

Comment: david's answer is more "real latex".  so go with that.  this one could be salvaged by changing the `\hss` to something like `\hskip -.15\linewidth` (or, better, `\hspace{-.15\linewidth}`) but the latex `\makebox` with 0 width does the "right thing".  xelatex doesn't matter in this situation.