# Centering wide 2x2 figure using adjustbox

Tags: subcaption, adjustbox

I have four large figures which I would like to tile 2x2. These figures will need to go beyond the \textwidth boundaries but I still want the 2x2 tile centered in the page. Looking at [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth) I've only been able to get the `\centerfloat` command from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27099) to produce the desired outcome. 
[image: what I want from adjustbox]

I'd like to be able to do this with the `adjustbox` package as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16584), but I'm having trouble getting creating the two rows of figures. Is it possible to get this functionality from the `adjustbox` package? I was trying to use the `minipage` option but haven't had success. This is what I currently get.
[image: what I current get with adjustbox]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mwe}% for this example only

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustbox}{center}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a version using `\makebox`.

Note: a `minipage` would reset `\textwidth`, but a `\parbox` doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\parbox{1.2\textwidth}{%
  \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}
}}
\caption{A $2\times2$ arrangement}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

---

Here is a version using `adjustbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{adjustbox}{center}
  \parbox{1.2\textwidth}{\lineskip=0pt
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}}
  \end{adjustbox}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:key}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is a version using neither,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \leftskip=-0.1\textwidth
  \rightskip=-0.1\textwidth
  \lineskip=0pt
  \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:key}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer works well without captions, which I forgot to include in my example and have updated. The second part of the linked answer uses `adjustbox`, it's the `center` command in the line `\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,center]{image}%`. Alternatively you can use adjustbox as `\begin{adjustbox}{center}` which I thought might be the way to do it. Are you able to modify your solution to work for captions, or possibly use adjustbox?

Comment: No problem.  There are many ways to overlay the margins.

Comment: @user3756 Hello, using `\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,center]{image}` by `adjustbox` displays no `center` parameter. Why?

Comment: You mean `[valign=center]` and `\usepackge[export]{adjustbox}`?

Answer (score 4):

You need `subfigure` only in case you have subcaptions. Otherwise, just treat the images as if they were big letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
%%% local settings
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular}

\caption{A $2\times2$ arrangement}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

By locally removing the interline spacing between rows (`\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}` and the intercolumn padding (`\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`) in the `tabular`, the images are placed next to each other with no space. Since the settings are done in a group (the `figure` environment), the values will be restored after `\end{figure}`, no need to reset them manually.

[image]

If you want oversized pictures, put the `tabular` in a box:

```
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image} \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}%
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately with your example when I make the figure wider than \textwidth (e.g. width=0.6\linewidth) the figure won't center in the middle of the page - I've updated the question to try and make that clear. 

I've also updated my post to include captions - I removed the caption to save space but I am looking for a more general solution. Do you think adjustbox would work for this situation?

Comment: @user3756 It's much easier than you think. I'll add it.

Comment: how much trouble is it to do the same thing but with captioned subfigures? I updated my post to mention captions because I forgot about them (sorry about that). However I could revert the question back to the original (non-caption) form and ask the caption question separately - what would you recommend?

Comment: @user3756 Since it is a completely different question, ask a new one. And, please, avoid changing your question so as to invalidate all given answers.