# Page number behaviour with memoir and adjustwidth environment crossing page break

Tags: margins, memoir, page-numbering, adjustwidth

When I use memoir and decrease the margin widths across a page break with the adjustwidth environment, the page number is pushed sideways. What's going on?

[image: page number too far to the right]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newlength{\extrawidth}
\setlength{\extrawidth}{50mm}

\newlength{\textwidthwide}
\setlength{\textwidthwide}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidthwide}{\extrawidth}

\newenvironment{widetext}
{\begin{adjustwidth}{-.5\extrawidth}{-.5\extrawidth}%
\setlength{\textwidth}{\textwidthwide}}%
{\end{adjustwidth}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext\Blindtext
\begin{widetext}
  \Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{widetext}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have reset `\textwidth` that has re-arranged the header. the intention of adjustwidth is to locally change the margins *without* changing the page setup. so just remove

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{\textwidthwide}
```

Comment: Aha! In that case, then this probably has the same problem?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth/154766#154766

Comment: @cmhughes uses it inside the table environment, so it wouldn't be a problem there...

Comment: @JosteinTrondal that's inside a table environment so doesn't affect the header (in fact it does nothing at all in the code as posted there)