# Move whole flowchart diagram left of the page when using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-styles, flow-charts

I am creating a flowchart using Tikz. Where under the main block, three blocks will share the equal space. I have tried with this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows, positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw]
\tikzstyle{line}= [draw,-latex',thick]
\tikzstyle{block}= [draw, rectangle,fill=gray!20, text width= 15em, minimum 
height=15mm,text centered, node distance = 8 em]
\tikzstyle{block_c}= [draw, rectangle,fill=gray!20, text width= 10em, 
minimum height=15mm,text centered, node distance = 8 em]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[block](A){xxx};

\node[block_c][below of =A](Data_c){Data collection feature};
\node[block_c][left of =Data_c,xshift=-80](B){Data collection feature};
\node[block_c][right of =Data_c,xshift=80](D){Data collection feature};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But problem is that, the whold flowchart is not center of the page(i.e., there is a huge space on the left side). Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as already said [koleygr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120578/koleygr) in his nice answer, your problem is that width of image is bigger than `\textwidth` beside this, it starts after `\parindent`. as reasonable solution is decrease size of blocks in your flowchart diagram. for example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows, shapes.geometric}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tikzset{
  block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=gray!20,
                  text width=#1, minimum height=15mm, align=flush center},
 block/.default = 9 em,
decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.2, draw, fill=green!30,
                   minimum width=9em,align=center}
        }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 6mm,
                        ]
\node[block=15em]       (A) {xxx};
\node[block,below=of A] (C) {Data collection feature};
\node[block, left=of C] (B) {Data collection feature};
\node[block,right=of C] (D) {Data collection feature};
\node[decision, below=of C] {is true?};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

note:

- picture is in the `center` environment. in real document probably it is in `figure` float
- i change the style's definitions syntax (`\tikzstyle` is consider as obsolete)
- in positioning of nodes is used syntax provided by library `positioning` (observe use of the `below=of A` instead of the `below of =A; the first specify distance between nodes' border, the second between nodes' centers)
- common nodes width is set to `9em` (instead of use `block-c` style), other width is defined locally as for example `block=15em`
- if you persist to have wider image than is width of text, than use [koleygr's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120578/koleygr) solution

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: Thank you very much. As I am writing an article, I would stick to your solution because it is important to maintain the similarity of the text width and image width.

Answer (score 3):

You have a wider than the `\textwidth` picture and this is the problem of the horizontal spaces.

Try adding some text to se the problem. Then it can be solved with the help of a `\makebox` command like in this post : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16584/120578
(Possible duplicate of that)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows, positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw]
\tikzstyle{line}= [draw,-latex',thick]
\tikzstyle{block}= [draw, rectangle,fill=gray!20, text width= 15em, minimum 
height=15mm,text centered, node distance = 8 em]
\tikzstyle{block_c}= [draw, rectangle,fill=gray!20, text width= 10em, 
minimum height=15mm,text centered, node distance = 8 em]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[block](A){xxx};

\node[block_c][below of =A](Data_c){Data collection feature};
\node[block_c][left of =Data_c,xshift=-80](B){Data collection feature};
\node[block_c][right of =Data_c,xshift=80](D){Data collection feature};
\end{tikzpicture}}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please do not upvote until we see if it is a duplicate (as the answer of the included link seems to solve OP's problem)

Comment: Thanks @koleygr, your solution worked for me...Thanks